# Is there a way to store data outside of the Activities?

Tags: android, model-view-controller, android-activity, android-intent

What I am interested in doing is creating a separate class, similar to a Model in a Model-View-Controller relationship, in which I can store all of my data so that each Activity can access its functions. I have started reading about Intents, but it still doesn't seem to be exactly what I'm looking for.

Am I not understanding Intents correctly? Or is there another way to do this?

Comment: Better try the [Getter & Setter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbbp.html)

Comment: make a java class as opposed to an activity

Comment: I understand Getter & Setter methods, but that wouldn't be the problem. I can write the class to store the information just fine, I'm just unsure how to initialize the object somewhere where each Activity can use it, unless I just pass it to each Activity as a parameter?

Owen -

Comment: Sorry, Owen, I'm new to Android, but from everything I have found out an Activity needs to start the Android application. I understand the data can be stored in just a regular class.

Comment: Have you look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878159/android-whats-the-best-way-to-share-data-between-activities or this one http://www.jameselsey.co.uk/blogs/techblog/android-implementing-global-state-share-data-between-activities-and-across-your-application/

Comment: make `Parcelable` Model class by implementing `Parcelable`. and pass it from one activity to another activity using Intent. initialize it in your first activity and to keep its existence pass it further  in your next activity to be used.

Comment: you can also use SharedPreferences  to store data in it and you can access data from this SharedPreferences  in every activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good answer on your question: http://chrisrisner.com/31-Days-of-Android--Day-7%E2%80%93Sharing-Data-Between-Activities

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Intents then use can pass the object in putExtra. 
[This SO post has a good example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139134/how-to-send-an-object-from-one-android-activity-to-another-using-intents)

Moreover use a singleton pattern so each class has reference to same object.

Answer (score 0):

You can also subclass the Application class and access that singleton instance from all Activities & Services