# Invoking a method of an object contained in another android activity

Tags: android, android-activity

In my app the activity which is currently running needs data from an activity which has started it. The parent activity has an object which method needs to be invoked to get the required data.

I am doing like this

### In the ParentActivity

```
public static Puzzle  puzzle;  // Puzzle is a class
```

### In the child activity

```
Puzzle puzzle = ParentActivity.puzzle;

ArrayList<String> cells = puzzle.getItemList();
```

It seems to work. But I am not sure about correctness of this approach. It allowed in android.
Will android run-time form destroying the parent activity.

Comment: why don't you test it yourself ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `Puzzle` is some plain object representing a data model, what you have is "correct" so long as you consider this to only be a cache and if `Puzzle` and its contents are fairly small.

Your process can be terminated at any time after it leaves the foreground. At that point, your cached `Puzzle` vanishes. Any data that needs to survive needs to be stored persistently: file, database, `SharedPreferences`, "the cloud", whatever. Your static `Puzzle` can be a cache of that persistent data, but the real data model is the persistent store, not the cached `Puzzle`.

Also, static data members represent intentional memory leaks. Anything referenced by that static `Puzzle` cannot be garbage collected. That works so long as the `Puzzle` is small. This is also why it is important for `Puzzle` to be an ordinary `Object`, not something more complex (e.g., an `Activity`) -- the more complex the object, the more memory you leak.

Answer (score 1):

Use google, this question was discussed a million times
[What's the best way to share data between activities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878159/android-whats-the-best-way-to-share-data-between-activities)

> public static Puzzle puzzle

puzzle is static, so it won't be destroyed after created even if Parent activity is gone. puzzle will be destroyed in 2 cases: you do it by yourself, your application process is finished. So it is safe to use your approche.

But I would recommend you to google "Share data between activities" and find a better way (singletone in application class for example).