# sending data to mysql from more then 1 screen

Tags: php, android, mysql

first let me say I am newbe.

I´m trying to make a android app for my work.

I have many info I need to send to a mysql (I know how to send to a mysql) but I have som many info, I need to spred it out on 5-6 pages, but how do I get the info from all the edittext info from page 1 to page 7 ( I use swipe)?

I hope you understand my quiestin.

A link to a site would be nice

Thanks
Dennis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably simply trying to share data across Activities (or Fragments). There are several ways to do this. Here is one good reference:

[What's the best way to share data between activities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878159/android-whats-the-best-way-to-share-data-between-activities)

Comment: hmmm how do I post my code ?