# How to create a global variable in android?

Tags: java, android, class, variables, global-variables

In my android application I need a place for putting the variable member id .
The problem is , it is getting from the online API and I need to find a way to store / retrieve it

I have tried to put it in a custom class , but the problem is , it will lose if I kill the activity, I have also know that there is a way to extends the application.

So  I would like to know what is the best way to store global variable?

I have to implment:

1. Save the variable on onSaveState
2. Save it on sharepref
3. Save it manually
4. Retrieve it manually

Thanks

**Update:** 
Thanks for reply. If I have just 3 variable (simple data e.g. a boolean , a phrase ), and I need it after app restart , should I simply use share pref to store it? What is the drawback of it? e.g. Will it harmful to the performance? thanks

Comment: Look up the singleton design pattern.

Comment: Please, don't look at singleton [anti-pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can create the global variable in android by declaring them in the class which extend the `Application` class.

Something like this.

```
class MyAppApplication extends Application {

    private String mGlobalVarValue;

    public String getGlobalVarValue() {
        return mGlobalVarValue;
    }

    public void setGlobalVarValue(String str) {
        mGlobalVarValue = str;
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle b){
        ...
        MyAppApplication mApp = ((MyAppApplication)getApplicationContext());
        String globalVarValue = mApp.getGlobalVarValue();
        ...
    }
}
```

## Update

This hold the value until your application is not destroyed. If you want to keep your values save even after your application instance destroy
then you can use the `SharedPreferences` best way to do this.

Learn about the `SharedPrefernces` from here : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Comment: what if i want to access these values outside the activity, say in some other layer ? i can't do getApplicationContext() there. AND i should not pass Context object around in different layers.

Comment: What about STATIC variable???

Comment: @GurgenHakobyan I think that we get the same instance of ```MyAppApplication``` when call ```getApplicationContext()``` and use static variables has the same effect.

Comment: How about performance when using this global variable ?

Answer (score 7):

- If you need a *global variable*, which is shared between multiple activities and survives their lifecycle changes, but is otherwise not persisted and would not survive an application restart, the method suggested in the first answer (extending `Application` and putting it there) is ok.
- If you need a *persisted global setting*, which should also survive an application restart, then you should use one of the other methods suggested. `SharedPreferences` is probably the easiest to use.

See also this Stack Overflow question: [What's the best way to share data between activities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878159/android-whats-the-best-way-to-share-data-between-activities)

Answer (score 2):

You can store it in a [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html), and create a sharedpreferenceHelper class to retrieve/store it.

Answer (score 1):

Its always better to store values which you want to use multiple times in one of the following ways:-

- Shared Preferences
- Singleton classes
- Write it to a file
- SQLite Database
- Store on the web-server

Comment: I disagree. It is only better, if the data is also required on restart of the app. If not, and the data for instance needs to be fresh on a fresh startup, the answer made by TGMCians fits the need.