# Using a static class to avoid frequent loading and releasing?

Tags: android, performance, android-memory

So, here is a known method to [share data between activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878159/android-whats-the-best-way-to-share-data-between-activities) and avoid frequent loading and releasing resources. However, I read an [article](http://www.curious-creature.org/2008/12/18/avoid-memory-leaks-on-android/) (which was referred to on Android official website) that says using a static field might result in memory leak. I am not entirely sure whether these two concepts are the same or not. Would anyone be able to shed some light on it? Any help is appreciated.

Code for my static data holder:

```
public class Art {

    public static Bitmap enemy;
    public static Bitmap player;

    public static void load () {
        enemy = loadBitmap('enemy.png');
        player = loadBitmap('player.png');
    }

    private static Bitmap loadBitmap(String filename) {
        //create and return bitmap here
    }

}
```

Code for context memory leak:

```
private static Drawable sBackground;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle state) {
  super.onCreate(state);

  TextView label = new TextView(this);
  label.setText("Leaks are bad");

  if (sBackground == null) {
    sBackground = getDrawable(R.drawable.large_bitmap);
  }
  label.setBackgroundDrawable(sBackground);

  setContentView(label);
}
```

Comment: See Android Official Website for memory leak code: http://android-developers.blogspot.ca/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables declared as `static` are created once the first instance of the class are created, or the first reference to that variable is called. This means that the object will live for the whole application lifetime and there's no way they will be removed from memory unless you explicitly set to `NULL`.

This being said, your static variable can be used in any way you want, but you need to be careful not to assign to it an object that you expect to deallocate. A simple example

```
public class Foo {
    static MyObject object;
    static void setObject(MyObject obj)
    {
        object = obj;
    }
}
```

Using `Foo.setObject(someObject)` would cause `someObject` never to be deallocated, because the `static` variable lives forever and is pointing to `someObject`, hence it will never be garbage collected.

A more complicated example:

```
public class Foo {
    static MyObject object;
    static void setBar(Bar bar)
    {
        object.bar = bar;
    }
}
```

Here the story is the same. `bar` will not be garbage collected because `object.bar` is pointing to it, and `object` is `static`. This is what happens in the example you pasted.

```
label.setBackgroundDrawable(sBackground);

public class Label { // just to illustrate the concept
    void setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable d) {
        // If d is static, callback is pointing to the label and will not be deallocated
        d.callback = this;
    }
}
```

Of course, you would need to know how `setBackgroundDrawable` works (which I didn't until reading the link you posted) in order to draw the conclusion that it could lead to a leak.

Comment: one question, if before `label.setBackgroundDrawable(sBackground);` I add another line: `sBackground.callback=null`. Would this solve the memory leak problem?

Comment: In my answer, I used `callback` as an example, but I don't think it's called that way (I made it up just to make my point). Even if this was possible, setting the callback to NULL before calling `setBackgroundDrawable` would have no effect. I  would suggest, as the article suggests, when you're finished using the Label, set the backgroundDrawable to NULL.

Answer (score 0):

The article  says that you should keep in mind what a particular object references internally when storing this object in a static variable.

This mainly depends on the parameters you use when creating the object. For `Bitmap` in particular this may be another `Bitmap` or a `Matrix` (depending on called `createBitmap()` method) but not e. g. a `Context` or a complete `View`-hierarchy.

So if you really need these bitmaps very often it is ok to store them in static variables.