# making data available between activities

Tags: android, android-activity, data-storage

I have four activities. Say A,B,C and D. What happens in my app is user fills data in each activity. First A then on completing the form goes to B then C and finally D. What I require are as follows:

1. Data inserted by user in activities A,B and C to be available in D.
2. If user navigates back like from D to C, I want the data user inserted previously to be   rendered in their respective fields.

Currently I am using intents to transfer data between the activities but it seems inefficient and tidious plus not a smart way. I thought of using shared preference or database but the data required are temporary. I mean once the process completes I don't require them in future.

I would like to know if there is a better way to make data available and persist in the activities.

Comment: You can use singleton pattern.

Comment: You can try use service too!

Comment: use shared preferences, after not used, remove them

Comment: @FahriyalAfif I made custom java objects for each page thinking it would make it easier. they are parceble. Is it possible to save custom object using shared preferences?

Comment: @Tim Can you be a little bit more clearer. You see I am a beginner and have little knowledge. which service are you talking about.

Comment: @Glenn-- I beleive singleton pattern is for making data persist. Thank you for your reply. I am looking over it.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

u can  use the service, to hold your data, and you can access/edit the data  by binding it to the service!
but, this method might be overkill for ur simple app

Comment: I have this question sometime back and this thread helped me a lot  [What's the best way to share data between activities?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878159/android-whats-the-best-way-to-share-data-between-activities