# How many ways we can pass data (objects) between activities in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, serialization

```
    I hope that we can pass data between android application components
```

by following ways.

1.we can pass data using intent object,

2.we can implement serializable , parcelable interface and pass objects by using intent,

3.we can create a new class by extending Application class, to access global members from anywhere

the android application,

4.sharedpreference ,

5.sqlite.

Are there any other mechanism to send data between android application components?

Comment: The other way is explained [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27033320/what-is-the-correct-way-to-share-data-between-different-activities-or-fragments/27033432#27033432

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option is create ApplicationPool.

Follow the below steps:-
 Initiate the ApplicationPool :-

```
ApplicationPool pool = ApplicationPool.getInstance();
```

modify the data on details page and add to pool

```
pool.put("key", object);
```

get the modified data on list page from pool

```
Object  object = (Object) pool.get("key");
```

important notes:- notify the listview or gridview after getting the data

ApplicationPool class file

```
public class ApplicationPool {

    private static ApplicationPool instance;
    private HashMap<String, Object> pool;

    private ApplicationPool() {
        pool = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    }

    public static ApplicationPool getInstance() {

        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new ApplicationPool();

        }

        return instance;
    }

    public void clearCollectionPool() {
        pool.clear();
    }

    public void put(String key, Object value) {
        pool.put(key, value);
    }

    public Object get(String key) {
        return pool.get(key);
    }

    public void removeObject(String key) {

        if ((pool.get(key)) != null)
            pool.remove(key);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use static elements, wether it be:

- Static fields (with public access for example)
- Static properties (meaning private fields with getter and/or setter)
- Singletons
- Possibly nested classes

While the use of static variables in OOP is debatable, they introduce global state and therefore are a way to accomplish sharing of data inbetween activities too.

Answer (score 1):

1) HashMap of WeakReferences, for example:

```
public class DataHolder {
  Map<String, WeakReference<Object>> data = new HashMap<String, WeakReference<Object>>();

  void save(String id, Object object) {
    data.put(id, new WeakReference<Object>(object));
  }

  Object retrieve(String id) {
    WeakReference<Object> objectWeakReference = data.get(id);
    return objectWeakReference.get();
  }
}
```

Before launching the activity:

```
DataHolder.getInstance().save(someId, someObject);
```

From the launched activity:

```
DataHolder.getInstance().retrieve(someId);
```

2) Or strange method: store data on server O_o