# Two activities access same variable

Tags: android

I was wondering if I have 2 activities that needs to update and access the same object . What would be the best way to do it? Should I use Application class? Or perhaps Static variable.. Etc?

Another option I can think of is putting it in a base class that both activities inherit. I will initialize the object from shared preferences during OnResume

Comment: Why do you need this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your object holds some kind of preference value, don't put it into a super-class. Make it static and/or use the [singleton](https://www.google.at/?gws_rd=cr&ei=B7TGVPXqOJLOaJL6gfAE#q=singleton) pattern and separate it from your application logic. This provides you with a more modular structure that will be easier to work with. The [application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) class is probably overkill; singletons do the job most of the time. (The Android docs simply states: "There is normally no need to subclass Application.")

You can add it to a super-class, if it is a logical part of it though.

Don't forget to synchronize your object if it's going to be accessed by another/several thread(s).

Answer (score 1):

There are different method to perform such requirement. Singleton is one of them. The other one is extending the application class. If you want a reference outlining all of these methods please see:
[What's the best way to share data between activities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878159/android-whats-the-best-way-to-share-data-between-activities)