# Share large data amount between activities

Tags: android, parcelable

I have a parcelable class that is trying to send some camera preview information. So I need to send several byte[] data from one activity to another. I'm using `Parcelable` with this code:

```
public class CameraResult implements Parcelable
{   
    private byte[] imagesList; 

    public CameraResult() {}

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeByteArray(imagesList);
    }

    public byte[] getImageList() {
        return imagesList;
    }

    public void setImageList(byte[] results) {
        this.imagesList = results;
    }


public static final Parcelable.Creator<CameraResult> CREATOR = new Creator<CameraResult>() {

    @Override
    public CameraResult[] newArray(int size) {
        return new CameraResult[size];
    }

    @Override
    public CameraResult createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        CameraResult toReturn = new CameraResult();

        int imageListSize = source.readInt();
        if (imageListSize != 0)
        {
            byte[] tempImageList = new byte[imageListSize];
            source.readByteArray(tempImageList);
            toReturn.setImageList(tempImageList);
        }

      return toReturn;
    }
};
}
```

This `Parcelable` class is working fine. But when I try to send a higher amount of data, the communication `Intent` is not working, as I exceed the maximum data size.

I read [this link](http://jyvee.com/passing-large-data-to-an-activity/) and [this other link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878159/android-whats-the-best-way-to-share-data-between-activities) with some supposed ways to solve my problem. But I would like to know if it's possible to send higher amounts of data using `Parcelable`, and if not, which of the mentioned ways is the most adequate one.

Thank you.

Comment: As a suggestion,why dont you use 2 fragments with a common activity?That way you cant use the activity for this form communication and there wont be any sending involved.\

Comment: Fragments is not a possibility due to some reasons why I'm discarding them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a singleton or static class to store the shared data.

---

EDIT:

According to my experience, that's the less painful way to do such a thing, but, also, on the first link you posted it says:

> There are several suggestions to achieve this, through defining global
>   variables, static fields, member variables, etc. Having tweaked those
>   ones a bit to get clean encapsulated code, I decided to implement it
>   using Java enum.

It uses a `enum` as DataHolder:

```
private enum DataHolder {
    INSTANCE;

    private List<Object> mObjectList;

    public static boolean hasData() {
        return INSTANCE.mObjectList != null;
    }

    public static void setData(final List<Object> objectList) {
        INSTANCE.mObjectList = objectList;
    }

    public static List<Object> getData() {
        final List<Object> retList = INSTANCE.mObjectList;
        INSTANCE.mObjectList = null;
        return retList;
    }
}
```

I personally prefer to implement a Singleton class as code seems to be more tidy in a different class (I'm a bit obsessed with that), but that's basically the same. Any other solution could be fine as well.

Comment: So you recommend one of the solutions I linked, no way to implement a `Parcelable` that shares big data amount?

Comment: This is a correct answer, it is not a good solution to store data inside the activities, fragments or views