# Android List view buttons text color changing when scrolling top to bottom?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a `ListView` and i populated that `ListView` with `TextView` and `Button` using custom adapter.I had generated a click event for that `Button` in custom adapter.In that click event i am trying to change the button text and color,up to here its working fine but when i scroll the `ListView` up and down the text color of other `Button` changing.I had stop here from past couple of days...

Here is some code which i had tried so far

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        View v=convertView;
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView ==null)
        {
            convertView = mInlfater.inflate(R.layout.attendancelistview,null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.b1 = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.row3);
            holder.tv1 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.row1);
            holder.tv2 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.row2);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder =(ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        //List<StudentData> data = list.get(position).Rno;
        holder.tv1.setText(String.valueOf(list.get(position).Rno));
        holder.tv2.setText(list.get(position).StudentName);
        holder.b1.setText(list.get(position).Attendance);
        holder.b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                if(holder.b1.getText().equals("Present"))
                {
                    holder.b1.setText("Absent");
                    //list.get(position).put("Attendance", "Absent");

                    holder.b1.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                }
                else if(holder.b1.getText().equals("Absent"))
                {
                    holder.b1.setText("Present");
                    //list.get(position).put("Attendance", "Present");
                    holder.b1.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                }
                String rno1=  String.valueOf(holder.tv1.getText());
                name=String.valueOf(holder.tv2.getText());
            }

        });
        return convertView;
    }
    static class ViewHolder
    {
        Button b1;
        TextView tv1,tv2,tv3;
    }
```

Comment: IS your holder.b1 text is changing?

Comment: Yes its changing but when i scroll down its again changing to previous text but color remains same

Comment: I found your issue .Check my answer. If you are not understand add comments. I will explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If holder.b1  button text is changing then the reason is you are not handling your getView properly.

I guess this returns some Integer id

```
list.get(position).Rno
```

So you need to store that id in some arraylist for example

```
//Declare this outside of getView().   
 ArrayList<Integer> your_number = new ArrayList();
```

And in your button click

```
holder.b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                if(holder.b1.getText().equals("Present"))
                {
                    holder.b1.setText("Absent");
                    //list.get(position).put("Attendance", "Absent");

                    holder.b1.setTextColor(Color.RED);
your_number.add(list.get(position).Rno);
                }
                else if(holder.b1.getText().equals("Absent"))
                {
                    holder.b1.setText("Present");
                    //list.get(position).put("Attendance", "Present");
                    holder.b1.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
your_number.remove(list.get(position).Rno);
                }
                String rno1=  String.valueOf(holder.tv1.getText());
                name=String.valueOf(holder.tv2.getText());
            }

        });
```

And finally in your getView()

```
if (your_number.contains(list.get(position).Rno)){
//set your text
}else{
//Set your text
}
```

Comment: In the on click event we have to call get View()  again right,in order to effect the changes

Comment: No need to call getView again. It will automatically call

Comment: But when i double click on button the application was stopping

Comment: Crashes are always happen. Don't worry about it. just tell what are the changes you made and what is the issue we will fix.

Comment: your_number.remove(list.get(position).Rno); removing this line works fine.

Comment: Is there any other thing wrong in my code,please comment it

Comment: I think it is not completed. You need to remove. Anyway if you have any issue ask

Comment: It is list.get(position).Rno int or Integer?

Comment: Its an int but not integer

Comment: Yes that is the issue. If you remove int from arraylist it is searching for the position not for value. So add and remove value as Integer.

Comment: One last question dont mind,can we pass the final list from custom adapter to Activity Class using SharedPreferences

Comment: You mean you need to pass (your_number) this to your same activity?

Comment: Yes exactly the rno added to your_number list wanted to pass in to my main activity

Comment: main activity means which contains this listview? If it so you don't need any sharedpreference. Just move ArrayList<Integer> your_number = new ArrayList(); this line to activity class

Comment: My custom Adapter Class is different and Activity Class is different how can it possible

Comment: There is many way to pass values. Try it on google. Refer this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878159/android-whats-the-best-way-to-share-data-between-activities this is good

Comment: I created custom adapter class with in the activity class.Everything is working fine.Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track of the buttons you have clicked, and set the colours accordingly to that.

Remember that your view is being reused so if you have a red button next time your view is reused (by scrolling up/down) it will still be red.

Use a List or some kind of container to store the clicked items and in your `getView` set the right values.

Answer (score 0):

As the same views are used for multiple times if you change the color for one item it will be applied to the another item with same reference. To avoid this when you click on a button get the position of the item and in getView() method based on the position change the text color.

**EDIT**

Add these lines to your `getView()` method before `holder.b1.setOnClickListener()` line

```
if(holder.b1.getText().equals("Present"))
 {
      holder.b1.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
 }
 else if(holder.b1.getText().equals("Absent"))
 {
      holder.b1.setTextColor(Color.RED);
 }
```

I didn't executed your code...but it may works and also remove comment for line `list.get(position).put("Attendance", "Absent");` and `list.get(position).put("Attendance", "Present");` in `onClick()` method.

Comment: Is there any refernce example