# Invalid cast when passing serializable object to activity

Tags: java, android, serialization

I have a complex object (which includes further objects and hashmaps). All objects implement `Serializable`.

In the first activity I do:

```
public void secondActivity(MyObject o) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("myobject", o);

    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

Then, in the second activity I'm doing:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    MyObject o = (MyObject)intent.getSerializableExtra("myobject");
}
```

But when casting I'm getting this exception:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to myapp.MyObject

Is this the correct way to pass complex objects between activities? What am I missing?

Or should I implement singleton class?

Comment: Does `getIntent()` return the same intent to which `myobject` extra was added?

Comment: @ChetanKinger It should. There's no other place in the app where the secondactivity gets opened from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing all fine, so I think that can be:

- your are sending to secondActivity method an incorrect object (like ArrayList instead of correct MyObject)
- Please look if you are using this key "myobject" in other part of the code and setting other object in putExtra.
- verify MyObject class and look if some variable is an ArrayList and remove it (just to test)
- your custom object not have "implements Serializable" like:

  public class MyObject implements Serializable {

  //variables and methods

  }

So, I suggest that you verify this, and I think is better use Singleton class or Parcelable instead of Serializable, because Google says that is better acording to Good Practice.
Please look this answer [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4878259/3314837)

I make some app and implement serializable, my custom object is:

```
public class Stores implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public Integer id;
public String name;
public String store_hours;
public String telephone;
public String fax;
public String latitude;
public String longitude;
```

}

My firt Activity:

```
private void showDialog(Stores store)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,DisplayDialogActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("Locations",store);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }
```

And my second activity

```
Stores store = (Stores) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("Locations");
```

PD: I don't know speak english very well, so apologize for this.

Answer (score 0):

- **There are some general guidelines that why some objects are not
  serializable**
- It is too closely tied to native code (java.util.zip.Deflater).
- The object's state depends on the internals of the virtual machine or
  the runtime environment and thus may change from run to run
  (java.lang.Thread, java.io.InputStream, java.io.FileDescriptor,
  java.awt.PrintJob).
- The class is mostly a holder for static methods without any real
  internal state (java.beans.Beans, java.lang.Math).
- The class is a nonstatic inner class. Serialization just doesn't work
  well with nonstatic inner classes. (Static inner classes have no
  problem being serialized.)
- An alternate serialization format is preferred in a particular
  context. (XOM node classes are not serializable because the proper
  serialization format for XML is XML.)

**Make sure your class is declared public**

> complete Reference . [Java I/O 2nd Edition](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596527501.do)