# How to track the accessToken facebook in many activities

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, access-token

Let us say we have 2 activities A and B. A is mainactivity which logins to facebook and also tracks the access token using AccessTokenTracker class. According to documentation, system should stop tracking token in onDestroy() method of activity A. Problem is I want to keep tracking accessToken in activity B too. Activity B also needs accessToken for graph API call. If token expires in the  Activity B, how can we keep track of it?

Answer (score 0):

How about saving it in `SharedPreferences`?

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
preferences.edit().putString(TOKEN, token).apply();
```

Comment: @matfred But access token is not string. I think even we change it into string using using AccessToken.getToken(), we cannot change it to accessToken later in next activity.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to share a parameter between your Acitivities, there are a couple of methods. Singleton is one of the easier one:

```
class DataHolder{

    private AccessToken ac;

    void setToken (AccessToken ac)
      {
       this.ac = ac;
      }

    AccessToken getToken()
      {
        return ac;
      }

}
```

If you want more details, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878159/android-whats-the-best-way-to-share-data-between-activities).

Comment: I don't want to pass the data from activity to activity. I want to track the accessToken when I am on activity B. If access Token expires on activity B,I need to track it and  get new access token.