# Call a method from MainActivity when a widget button is clicked

Tags: java, android, methods, widget

I would like to call a specific method from my `MainActivity` on click of a widget button in my `AppWidgetProvider`. I have already set up the layout which only has one button in it and already created the `widget.xml`. My problem is that nothing happens when I click the button I want to call the methods from My `MainActivity` from.

This is my AppWidgetProvider class

```
public class NewAppWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

        final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds[i]);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDisabled(Context context) {

    }

    static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                                int appWidgetId) {
        CharSequence widgetText = context.getString(R.string.appwidget_text_balance);

        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.new_app_widget);

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);

    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
    }
}
```

And this is my MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
     public void makeText(String message){
        Toast.makeText(this,message,Toast.LENGHT_SHORT).show();

     }
     public void calculateData(){

       //Something in here
     }
  }
```

and this is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<!--declare new widget-->
<receiver android:name=".NewAppWidget" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
    </intent-filter>

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
        android:resource="@xml/new_app_widget_info" />
</receiver>
```

Comment: Why not Declare calculateData() in different class and this function take some argument to do the calculation and you can call this new class anywhere , in MainActivity or in your widget class , But still you can try MainActivity obj=new MainActivity(); and call your function like this obj.calculateData();

Answer (score 1):

Basically what you are asking for is to share a method between 2 classes, am I right?

There are quite a few approaches to this, it's just like sharing any other data.

Use a class that can be accessed globally:

**i.e -**

```
public class GlobalMethods{

    public static void calculateData(){
        ....
    }

}
```

and access it from within your other class file:

```
GlobalMethods.calculateData(...);
```

I'm guessing you want to call `calculateData()` from within your mainActivity because there may be data in that class you want to edit.

If this is the case, maybe you should consider sharing the data between activities / classes using an interface or a singleton.

Look at some examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4878259/5132172) on how this is done.

Not all examples will apply to your situation, but you should get some ideas from there.