# How to Activate Button?

Tags: java, android

my context menu has two options Silly and Cool. I want to provide one item named activate to list item silly and second item named deactivate to list item cool.
How can i do that.??????
Help

Comment: Well you can use **Intent** to call second activity and your question is confusing which button you are talking about button in first activity or button present in second activity

Comment: Button means by clicking context item 1.

Comment: What will be the code of intent?

Comment: startActivity(new Intent(Profile.this, Custom.class)); you have used it already use put extra feature to make your calling custom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.If you want to start the `second activity`(and activate the settings) when `Activate button` is pressed you can use `Intent` to send a `String` or `Integer`(0 or 1) to know in the `second activity` that button was pressed.

You can find more information about sending data with `Intent` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878159/android-whats-the-best-way-to-share-data-between-activities)

2.If you don't want to start the second activity when button is pressed but still activate the settings, you can make another `class(Utils.java)` where you can define all your `settings`(vibration, volume, ringtone) in methods and call them like that:

`Utils mUtils = new Utils();
mUtils.activateVibration();
mUtils.playRingTone();
mUtils.setVolume(volumeLevel);`

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanx for your guidence.Please tell me where i should add this piece of code. In my profile file or in custom ? Or should i create this class seperately?

Comment: You should create Utils class separately so you can acces it from any activity you want.

Comment: Now there is a little issue. After activation it opens a blank activity  but i do not need this activity. I just want to redirect it to activity back the activity from which it was called !! Help me..

Comment: How did you created your Utils class? New Java class or New Blank Activity? I think you created another activity and you put all the code in `onCreate` method. If you did like that it's wrong. `You need to create a New Java Class`, not Activity. Tell me how you did it.

Comment: I created new java class that extends activity. But i did not write any setContext() .yea i called my playRingTone() in onCREATE method.

Comment: Dont extend Activity, create a clean class. Your blank activity appears because you extended Activity and start the window with Intent at button pressing.

Comment: If you think I helped you please accept my answer as the correct one, or give it an Up Vote

Answer (score 0):

You can use intent.putExtra - put some information there, for example some object, String, whatever you want.

Then in your second activity just get those extras by

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
```

And for example if u have some boolean stored then you do:

```
boolean something = extras.getBoolean("keyToThatBoolean");
```

Comment: Ok. I try to go with your given logic then inform you.