# saving activity state between screen navigations

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-4.4-kitkat

I would like to save state of an `activity` when you navigate away from it. For example, you have `Activity A` with filled in text on it and you navigate to `Activity B` using an `intent`. Well when you go back to `Activity A` using an `Intent` you lose all the text you had on that screen.

When I use the soft key back button on most android phones, the screens text stays on there, I would like to mimic that method of keeping the text on screen between navigation.

The last thing I want to do is pass parameters between all my screens, there are a lot of forms and the users dont have to follow a specific nav order.

Comment: you could create a singleton to represent the data on the screen you want to save, then reference the singleton when the screen is reloaded

Comment: I'll have a look at how those work, ty

Comment: here is a good post which outlines a few different methods of achieving your first goal (including the singleton method which I suggested): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878159/whats-the-best-way-to-share-data-between-activities

Comment: You should save activity data in onPause() method, it's the most safe method to save data when activity or fragment is supposed to go off the screen. Singleton might raise any issue if you're opening same activity from multiple activities and you're passing different data everytime, you'll have to nullify those data explicitly.