# Android AccesToken is null

Tags: android, android-intent, access-token, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm developing an application based on Facebook 4.0 login.
The user can log in in Login.activity and then the main.Activity is shown.

After user successfully logged in, AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() is not null and I'm able to perform a Graph Request.

```
 ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground(...)
```

Then

```
AccessToken token = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
if(token != null)
    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(token, ...)
```

But then after my Intent, AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() is always null.

Do you have any idea why AccessToken cannot be used across acitivies ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can declare your AccessToken as static, in MainActivity, then initialize it in onCreate, and then you can use it in other activities.

Or a best way, is to share it throw your intent, look here, [What's the best way to share data between activities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878159/whats-the-best-way-to-share-data-between-activities)

Send data inside intents

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("some_key", value);
intent.putExtra("some_other_key", "a value");
startActivity(intent);
```

On the second activity:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
int value = bundle.getInt("some_key");
String value2 = bundle.getString("some_other_key");
```

PS: the snipped code was toked from the shared post

Comment: But I guess thah AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() is already static. I don't understand why it gets null after my intent ..

Comment: Have you passes the data from your activty throw that intent ?

Comment: I have just done this.startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class)); in my Login.acitivity when user succesfully logged in

Comment: ok, good. But you must share that date throw your activities, and you can do through your intents or by making a variable static. here is an example to how could you passed it . Send data inside intents

Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("some_key", value);
intent.putExtra("some_other_key", "a value");
startActivity(intent);

On the second activity:

Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
int value = bundle.getInt("some_key");
String value2 = bundle.getString("some_other_key"); PS: this is toked from the shared post.