# Pass data from inner View to Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, view, pass-data

I have an activity that contains a View.

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second_act);

        LinearLayout surface = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView1);
        surface.addView(new PlacingBoxView(this));
        surface.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

        if (ACTIONS_FINISHED){
            Log.d("TAG", "i made it!!");
        }
    }
```

Within the `PlacingBoxView` i do some actions, and once they are finished I set the a boolean called `ACTIONS_FINISHED` to true. My goal is once I've set this boolean to true then do some actions in the activity automatically.

I've been trying to use [all this possibilities](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4878259/5176549), but they are just to share information. Maybe I should use onActivityResult, but I'm already within the activity...

Any idea? THanks in advance!

**EDIT:** The view performs an AsyncTask and draws several shapes, but the user doesn't touch the screen at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a interface in your `PlacingBoxView` class:

```
public class PlacingBoxView{
   private GetCallBack callback;

   public PlacingBoxView(Context context){
         callback = (GetCallBack) context;
   }

   public void someMethodWhichSendsData(){
         callback.onMessageReceived(msg);
   }


   public interface GetCallBack{
       void onMessageReceived(Object msg);
   }
}
```

Now in your `activity` implement the interface:

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements PlacingBoxView.GetCallBack{

 @Override
 public void onMessageReceived(Object msg){
    // you have got your msg here.
 }


}
```

Comment: Perfect Interface! Given that I'm using a view and not an Activity in `PlacingBoxView` you should just change the `Àctivity activity` with `Context context` and I'll mark it right! Thank you for the help ;)

Comment: @Alvaro I made the change you requested in the answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

> I've been trying to use all this possibilities, but they are just to share information. Maybe I should use onActivityResult, but I'm already within the activity...

No, `onActivityResult()` got different purpose. What you shall do is implement ordinary listener in your View and then attach your activity to view's listener (same way you do with i.e. `OnClickListener`). That way your view will be able to call back when needed and trigger some actions in Activity that way.