# How to make a TextView with incremental score in multiple activities (Quiz game without database)

Tags: java, android, textview, increment

I'm a beginner and i'm trying to make a quiz game without database and multiple activities. I want to get the scoring system as a textview in all the activities and it should change according to right or wrong answer. I've been trying to figure it out for over a week now and I only think I wasted that time. Here is a sample code. All help will be appreciated.

my Page4.java

```
    public class Page4 extends AppCompatActivity {
int score = 0;
TextView scored1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);;
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_page4);
    scored1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
    scored1.setText(String.valueOf(score));
}
public void nocircle(View view){
    score = score + 5;
    scored1.setText(String.valueOf(score));
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,Page5.class);
    intent.putExtra("score",String.valueOf(score));
    startActivity(intent);
    ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeScaleUpAnimation(view, 0,
            0, view.getWidth(), view.getHeight());
    startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
}
}
```

activity_page4

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#05083e"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Score"
            android:id="@+id/tvLabelScore"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#f6f6f6"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/score"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#e5e5e5"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView10"
    android:text="NO"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:fontFamily="casual"
    android:textSize="70sp"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/answeryes"
    android:onClick="nocircle"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

When the new activity Page5.class begins, the textview is 5...but when I click the button the score gets reset and only 5 points are added. I want it in such a way that the points add the Page4.java score and this Page5.java score and display in the textview....and continue with the same for the next activity.

Page5.java code

```
    public class Page5 extends AppCompatActivity {


int score = 5;
TextView scored;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);;
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_page5);
    scored = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score1);

    Intent mintent = getIntent();
    String score = mintent.getStringExtra("score");
    scored.setText(String.valueOf(score));

}
public void rightanswer(View view){


    scored.setText(String.valueOf(score));
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Page6.class);
    intent.putExtra("ta_score",String.valueOf(score));
    startActivity(intent);
    ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeScaleUpAnimation(view, 0,
            0, view.getWidth(), view.getHeight());
    startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());

}


 }
```

and finally my activity_page5

```
      <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#05083e"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Score"
        android:id="@+id/tvLabelScore"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#f6f6f6"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/score1"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#e5e5e5"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

    android:onClick="rightanswer"
    />
```

Any help would be awesomely appreciated with kind words of praise.

Comment: I'd use a `static` variable in a class. So that I could change that value from wherever in my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you aren't actually doing the addition of the previous score (page 4) to the current score (page 5) anywhere.

Also, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878159/whats-the-best-way-to-share-data-between-activities) is a link to several ways you can share data between activities, although you're already using one of them.

**Update:**

To add them you just to the addition with the values you already have, so:

```
public void rightanswer(View view){

    score += Integer.parseInt(scored.getText()); //add them right there

    scored.setText(String.valueOf(score));
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Page6.class);
    intent.putExtra("ta_score",String.valueOf(score));
    startActivity(intent);
    ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeScaleUpAnimation(view, 0,
        0, view.getWidth(), view.getHeight());
    startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
```

}

Comment: The addition code is what I don't know...can you help me with that?

Comment: Also, you can pass values in your intent as an integer. I would suggest you do that for your scores and then use intent.getIntExtra()