# Passing RelativeLayout through intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-relativelayout

Is there a way to pass a `RelativeLayout` through intent to the next Activity?
I am having this error:

```
android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to java.io.Serializable
```

by using this:

```
getIntent().putExtra("Layout", (Serializable) layout);
```

Thanks.

Comment: why do you want to pass `RelativeLayout ` via Intent?

Comment: I have a relativeLayout in another activity with sufaceViews inside it. When I click on the relativeLayout, I want to duplicate the relativeLayout to the next Activity

Answer (score 1):

I just found out that there are other ways to pass data between activities here: [What's the best way to share data between activities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878159/whats-the-best-way-to-share-data-between-activities)

..and I used a singleton class to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your activity 's Relative layout bind itself, you cannot using it in other activity. Using Dynamic layout instead, click -> go to other activity -> generate your layout programmatically.
[Here is some search result.](https://www.google.com/?q=android%20layout%20programmatically)