# Android. Passing this custom object to next Activity?

Tags: java, android

I have this custom object which I want to pass to a different Activity:

```
public class FindRouteOutputForDisplay {
    public ArrayList<VertexDisplay> vertexDisplayArrayList;
    public ArrayList<Integer> integerArrayList;
}
```

I tried this, but doesn't work.

```
Intent newIntent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
FindRouteOutputForDisplay data = getMyData();
newIntent.putExtra("data", data); // Error
startActivity(newIntent);
```

Should I pass

```
    public ArrayList<VertexDisplay> vertexDisplayArrayList;
    public ArrayList<Integer> integerArrayList;
```

separately one-by-one? Any way to pass all of them at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this solution.

```
public class FindRouteOutputForDisplay implements Serializable{
   public ArrayList<VertexDisplay> vertexDisplayArrayList;
   public ArrayList<Integer> integerArrayList;
}

Intent newIntent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
FindRouteOutputForDisplay data = getMyData();
newIntent.putSerializable("data", data); 
startActivity(newIntent);
```

If you have any errors on "putSerializable" so you can cast your object to Serializable in this way.

```
newIntent.putSerializable("data", (Serializable)data);
```

And in your activity just get your data by this

```
FindRouteOutputForDisplay data = getIntent().getSerializable("data");
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: "newIntent.putSerializable()" doesn't exist

Comment: after adding " implements Serializable", using "newIntent.putExtra()" worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Save your data in your application context class. Since this class is available across your application instance, you can get or set the variables defined inside this class from all activities. More info [here](http://androidexample.com/Global_Variable_Or_Application_Context_Variable_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=114)

Answer (score 0):

Change this :

```
startActivity(routeDetailIntent);
```

To :

```
startActivity(newIntent);
```

Comment: sorry, that was just a typo.. not the cause of the problem

Answer (score 0):

You should make the custom objects implement the [Parcelable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) interface:

```
public class MyParcelable implements Parcelable {
    private int mData;

     public int describeContents() {
         return 0;
     }

     public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
         out.writeInt(mData);
     }

     public static final Parcelable.Creator<MyParcelable> CREATOR
         = new Parcelable.Creator<MyParcelable>() {
         public MyParcelable createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
             return new MyParcelable(in);
         }

         public MyParcelable[] newArray(int size) {
             return new MyParcelable[size];
         }
     };

     private MyParcelable(Parcel in) {
         mData = in.readInt();
     }
}
```

You can also have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878159/whats-the-best-way-to-share-data-between-activities) if you want other solutions.

Comment: from "private MyParcelable(Parcel in) {
         mData = in.readInt();
     }", How can I use it for multiple class variables?

Comment: You can write many variables into the parcel - you must just make sure the in order and out order are the SAME (https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-parcelable)

Answer (score 0):

you have passed wrong intent to start activity.

```
Intent newIntent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("value", data );
newIntent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(newIntent );
```

Comment: sorry, that was just a typo.. not the cause of the problem

Comment: it did after adding " implements Serializable", and didn't need to have "new Bundle()"

Answer (score 0):

I have a trick for you. Add Gson to your dependencies.

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
}
```

Convert your object to Json and ship it as a String.

```
String data = new Gson().toJson(getMyData())
```

Convert it back from String in a new Activity

```
FindRouteOutputForDisplay data = new Gson(stringData, FindRouteOutputForDisplay.class).
```

Comment: is this not expensive?

Comment: Nope, it is light-weight. It'll have 0 impact on your performance or memory.

Comment: Doesn't GSON use reflection? That is not cheap

Comment: By all means if you have unlimited time in your life you can optimize to death. Remember though - premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Answer (score 0):

I also face this problem so I'm trying this below code:

Pass the object with intent

In starting activity we can set the parcelable object to an intent

```
User user = new User("1", "u", "u", "u");

ArrayList<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();

Sensor sensor = new Sensor("1", "s", "s", true, user, userList);

intent.putExtra("com.score.senzors.pojos.Sensor", sensor);
```

In destination activity we can get the parcelable object from intent extras(bundle)

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

Sensor sensor = bundle.getParcelable("com.score.senzors.pojos.Sensor")
```

Hope it Helps you

Answer (score 0):

You can make the class static and use it anywhere in your app.