# How to share a java object reference between android components

Tags: java, android, event-bus

Lately I've read this comment on Reddit:

> I think **EventBus** on android is popular because people don't know how to share a java object reference between android components like a Fragment and an Activity, or 2 Activities and so on. So basically I think people don't know how 2 Activites can observe the same object for data changes which I think comes from the fact that we still don't know how to architect our apps properly.

As far as I know:

- directly reference values

  `((HostActivity)getActivity()).someValue`

  > may cause problem such as memory leaks or `NullPointerException`
- Callbacks or other observer pattern

  **EventBus**,inner class like  `listener` and etc

So I was curious that whether there is any other ways , could you share with me on it?

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878159/whats-the-best-way-to-share-data-between-activities) is an excellent answer

Answer (score 0):

imo, there are few ways out of your opinion such as:

- use **local db**, now ORM like `Realm` is really popular, its also safe way.
- use **share preferences** if your object is able to convert to json, its up to your situation.
- use **intent** with `serialize/parcelable` object bundle.
- use a **singleton**, now `@scope` with `Dagger 2` is good choice.
- use **RxJava** as event bus.