# Pass variable value to class (NOT intent) from home activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I need to update a variable (via setter, I think) in a class that is not the intent class of a button. I need to set *c* to a given value in *Creator* from the Home activity. The chosen activity will then use *Item Creator*.

Home Activity:

```
    int c;

    public void setC(int c) {
        this.c = c;
    }

    public void one(View view) {
        setC(1);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, One.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void two(View view) {
        setC(2);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Two.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void three(View view) {
        setC(3);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Three.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void four(View view) {
        setC(4);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Four.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public int getC() {
        return c;
    }

}
```

Class I am trying to pass *c* to:

```
public class Creator{
    HomeActivity home = new HomeScreenActivity();
    private int c = home.getC();
```

If I manually change *c*'s value...

```
int c = 3;
```

... the class I want to receive it gets it fine. The issue seems to be getting the buttons to setC().

Thank you for any advice!

Comment: `new HomeScreenActivity`... No, bad.. NEVER make a `new` Activity

Comment: What do you have against intent extras? Because that is the clearest solution to what I think you're doing

Comment: use Shared Preference to store "c" value, then on Creator class retrieve that value from Shared Preference.

Answer (score 0):

1. As far as your original question, I'd suggest using [intents](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html):

   [What's the best way to share data between activities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878159/whats-the-best-way-to-share-data-between-activities)
2. cricket_007 is correct: use [startActivity()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivity(android.content.Intent)), not "new HomeScreenActivity()":

   https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html