# Why does Android use parcels to pass data between components?

Tags: android, parcelable, parcel

Why does Android use parcels to pass data between components (e.g. two Activities)? Why not just a reference to the object?

Comment: Actually, it's `Bundle` between Activities, but close enough

Answer (score 1):

`Parcel` is a container for a message(data and object references). In transmission, `Parcel` contains a byte stream version of a chosen Java `Object` that contains information about it's attributes. Such data is written to `Parcel` at sending component, and is read at receiving component. Because the protocol is also designed to support IPC(Inter-Process Communication), only a reference wouldn't suffice. If you really want to use just a reference you can declare your object containing data `public static`, although I wouldn't recommend this because of the global scope & tight coupling of components.

Comment: `Because the protocol is also designed to support IPC(Inter-Process Communication), only a reference wouldn't suffice.` yep this is why, Activities can belong to a different app than your own.

Answer (score 0):

If we look at [common ways of sharing data between activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878159/whats-the-best-way-to-share-data-between-activities), we can make a reasonable guess at why this is the case.

Alternatives include using singletons and `SharedPreferences` - entities that basically act as "owners" of the state stored by the data. The use of a third party keeps the activities decoupled, as compared to activities simply giving each other references.

We want activities to be decoupled since any two [activities](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) should be fairly distinct entities, with possibly independent lifecycles. This is why if we can simply pass information by value (rather than keep a live reference dependency), we should. This is also why it's comparable to Inter-Process Communication, which works around the lack of shared memory.