# How to use a value across all activities?

Tags: android

For example: I have a String value "A". and I have activities : activity_a, activity_b, activity_C.

Can I use value "A" across all activities? If yes how to achieve this? 
And not through Intent or send data to another activity.

I am sorry that I am not fluent in English.

I moved a token value in login activity to main activity.
I used Intent and move token login activity. this is my login activity code.

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, serverURL,
                                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                                            try{
                                                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);

                                                JSONObject json_code = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                                                JSONObject json_token = jsonArray.getJSONObject(1);

                                                String code = json_code.getString("code");
                                                String token = json_token.getString("token");

                                                Intent myIntent = new Intent(loginActivity.this, mainActivity.class);
                                                myIntent.putExtra("token", token);
                                                startActivity(myIntent);
                                                finish();

                                                overridePendingTransition(R.xml.madefadein, R.xml.splashfadeout);

                                            }catch(JSONException e){
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                    switch(error.networkResponse.statusCode)
                                    {
                                        case 409:
                                            Toast.makeText(loginActivity.this, error.networkResponse.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            break;
                                    }

                                }
```

but in main Activity, I tried to declare static like this.

```
Intent i = new Intent(getIntent());
public static final String token = i.getStringExtra("token");
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: use sharedprefference for this

Comment: make it static e.g. public static String activity_a="some string"; then access from other with MainActivty.activity_a

Comment: `String strA_fromActivity_A = Activity_A.strA;`

Comment: [Check this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878159/whats-the-best-way-to-share-data-between-activities)

Comment: do you want pass data from one activity to other ..?

Comment: @NileshRathod no. I must use token in all activity. At First, I move a value to use Intent. Login Activity to Main Activity. but It is so complex. then I find how to use any value in all activity easily. I tried declared static but it say Non-static field can't be referenced from a static context.

Comment: @DongHyeongJeong just check my ans and let me know if any query

Comment: @NileshRathod Thank you every time. :)

Comment: @DongHyeongJeong did your problem solved

Comment: @NileshRathod I'm trying now. but server developer said token must save on database. The token should be saved when application is off. may be I have to use SQLite... I'm finding now how to use SQLite.

Comment: you can save it in shared prefrence

Comment: @DongHyeongJeong check updated ans

Comment: @NileshRathod Is That answer can save data when application is off?

Comment: @NileshRathod wait I will try

Comment: yes it can save data

Comment: @NileshRathod These codes are should type in one activity?

Comment: when your wan to save data in `SharedPreferences` than use **save** code and when you want to **retrieve** than use **retrieve code**

Comment: @NileshRathod At retrieve code, String name = myPref.getBoolean("TOKEN", ""); occured error. why use getBoolean method? There is a redline on "".

Comment: @DongHyeongJeong sorry my mistake just change it with `getString("TOKEN", "");` check updated ans

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1.just declare your String as** `public static String strTmp="A";` in your activity than you can use any where in your project

like this

```
 String strTmp = yourActivity.str;
```

**2. create a new class like this**

```
public class ServiceClass {  
    public static String strTmp="Data";
}
```

**now you can access this string anywhere in your project like this**

`String mystr= ServiceClass.strTmp;`

**3.if you want use hard String than store your string in** **res/values/string.xml** like this

```
<resources>
  <string name="app_name">PatternView</string>
</resources>
```

than you can use like this

```
String str = getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
```

**4. save it in SharedPreferences like this**

> code for save data in SharedPreferences like this

```
SharedPreferences myPref;
SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor;

myPref = getSharedPreferences("TOKENNAME", MODE_PRIVATE);
prefEditor = myPref.edit();

prefEditor.putString("TOKEN", "your token");
prefEditor.apply();
```

**code for retrieve data  from SharedPreferences**

```
SharedPreferences myPref;
myPref = getSharedPreferences("TOKENNAME",
            MODE_PRIVATE);

    String name = myPref.getString("TOKEN", "");
```