# How to save a serialized object state when I am passing it using Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have the following Classes:

```
public class Creature implements Serializable {
protected String name;

public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
// Rest of the methods and variables
}
```

Player Class extends Creature:

```
public class Player extends Creature implements Serializable {
// Class code
}
```

I am passing an instance of `Player` from one activity to another using `Intents`:

```
// Activity A, passing the object
Intent charActivity= new Intent(this, CharacterActivity.class);
charActivity.putExtra("Player", player);
startActivity(goToCharacterActivity);

// Activity B, grabbing the object
Player player = (Player) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("Player");
```

Now if I do something like `player.setName("Hello");` in activity B the "original" object name doesn't update, the new name will be valid only in this current activity, because I only have a local "copy" of the object. How do I go around this if I must use Serializable?

Comment: You can't do that, you need to use some other method to pass information between activities see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878159/whats-the-best-way-to-share-data-between-activities

Comment: use startActivityForResult(goToCharacterActivity) and pass this object to orginal activity in new activity using setResult method

Comment: @Cyrus I have tried that, when I am overriding `onActivityResult` I can get the `player` object passed from the activity B however I can't assign it to my variable in the `Activity A` The scope is only local, once the `onActivityResult` is out of scope the variable points to the previously assigned object...

Comment: @HarisK. Why don't your change your local variable  to global  variable . what's  more , according to my experience ,only updating member would be  passed not whole object .

Answer (score 0):

If you want them to reference the same Object in memory you cannot use `Serializable` or `Parcelable`.  (A new Object will automatically be created in memory).

In this case I'd recommend having a shared class with static fields that hold your information. E.g.:

SharedInfo:

```
public class SharedInformation {
    public static Creature theCreature;
}
```

Activity A:  start using the Intent as usual, but don't pass the `Person` or `Creature`

Activity B:

```
SharedInformation.theCreature.setName("Hello");
```

Answer (score 0):

I have one example with a List of players in github. What I did is to use onActivityResult and startActivityForResult methods those allows to return values between two activities. You can see the full example and download the code from my github [repoitory](https://github.com/saulrb/android_futbol_team_app/blob/master/app/src/main/java/mx/itesm/m6_srb_ejer_futbol/MainActivity.java).

Answer (score 0):

Because your intent  name is not the same .

```
Intent charActivity= new Intent(this, CharacterActivity.class);
```

You use `charActivity` as the name .

Change

```
startActivity(goToCharacterActivity);
```

to

```
  startActivity(charActivity);
```

Comment: This was a copy and paste error from my code when I was renaming my variables to better explain the problem. This is working as intended in my code, the problem lies in the fact that modifying `player` inside the `charActivity` doesn't change the object in the other activity. This is what I want to do..

Answer (score 0):

if u want passing between Activity try Bundle like this

Activity 1 :

```
Intent i =  new Intent(this,CharacterActivity.class);
Bundle playerBundle = new Bundle();
playerBundle.putSerializable("Player",player);
i.putExtras(playerBundle);
startActivity(i);
```

and this is how to retrieve the bundle at Activity 2:

```
Player player = (Player) getIntent.getSerializableExtra("Player");
```

and remember the key between that intent must same in this example i'm using

- Player

as key