# How to use Singleton class to pass list data from one fragment to another?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, singleton

**My Singleton Class:** Here's the Singleton class I found on Official Documentations.

```
    public class Singleton {
    private static Singleton uniqInstance;
    private Singleton() {
    }
    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        if (uniqInstance == null) {
            {
                if (uniqInstance == null)
                   uniqInstance = new Singleton();
            }
        }
        return uniqInstance;
    }
   }
```

**My First Fragment:** This is my first fragment, Here I'm Adding ArrayList items with object class Names.

```
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup 
          container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
          View mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container,false);
          RecyclerView rvFirst = mView.findViewById(R.id.rv_first_layout);
          rvFirst.setHasFixedSize(true);
          rvFirst.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mView.getContext()));
          mArrayList = new ArrayList<Names>();
          mArrayList.add(new Names("Hello"));
          mArrayList.add(new Names("This"));
          mArrayList.add(new Names("Is"));
          mArrayList.add(new Names("Android"));

          // HERE I WANT TO SEND ARRAY-LIST DATA TO THE SECOND FRAGMENT
          mAdapter = new NameAdapter(mArrayList);
          rvFirst.setAdapter(mAdapter);
          return mView;
    }
```

**My Second Fragment:** This is my second fragment, Here I'm trying to get ArrayList items from First Fragment.

```
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup 
          container,Bundle savedInstanceState){
          View mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_second, container,false);
          rvSecond = (RecyclerView) mView.findViewById(R.id.rv_second_layout);
          rvSecond.setHasFixedSize(true);        
          rvSecond.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));        
          mArrayList = new ArrayList<Names>(); 

          // HERE I WANT TO GET ARRAY-LIST FROM FIRST FRAGMENT     
          mAdapter = new NameAdapter(mArrayList);
          rvSecond.setAdapter(mAdapter);
     return mView;
   }
```

Comment: what is the relation between your singleton class and arraylist?

Comment: @HemantParmar I don't know actually, but we have to pass object data over two fragments using creating a method in the singleton class.

Comment: have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4878259/5110595), it will give all possibilities for passing data over fragment/activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First set the arraylist inside the singleton class like this

**Your singleton class should be like this:-**

```
public class Singleton {
private static Singleton uniqInstance;
public ArrayList<Names> names = new ArrayList<Names>();;
private Singleton() {
}
public static Singleton getInstance() {
    if (uniqInstance == null) 
         uniqInstance = new Singleton();
    return uniqInstance;
}
public void setArrayList(ArrayList<Names> names)
 {
      this.names = names;

     }
 public ArrayList<Names> getArrayList()
 {
      return this.names;

     }
}
```

> In your first fragment after adding values in list:-

```
Singleton.getInstance().setArrayList(mArrayList);
```

> In your second fragment get it like this :-

```
Singleton.getInstance().getArrayList();
```

Answer (score 2):

why using singleton for this, if your both fragments are attached to the same activity then you can do this,

first create a public list variable in your acitivity class

then reference it from your fragment classes by its context like

```
((YourActivityClass)getActivity()).myArrayList.get(i);
```

Comment: #Abhinay Sharma...what if i need the same data in the fragment not attached with the same activity,that's the reason singleton class is necessarily to get data anywhere in your application.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it through the hosting Activity or store it in the extended Application class. [Official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html).

Other options include [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus), Intent, MessageLooper.

The EventBus is dead simple but if you overuse it the code will become spaghetti.

Answer (score 0):

> To pass data between fragment follow these steps :

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
putParcelableArrayList("ArrayListKey", mArrayList);

Fragment fragment = new MasterSearchTabFragment();
fragment.setArguments(bundle);

//Add Fragment while starting it   
getFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.frame_layout_root_container, fragment)
                .commit();
```

> In Second Fragment :

```
 Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
 mBundle = getArguments();

if (null != mBundle) {
    ArrayList arrayList =  getParcelableArrayList("ArrayListKey");
}
```