# How to send the response to new activity?

Tags: android, json, android-intent, android-activity, response

I want to pass my API response to another activity . I am using intent but getting null in the next activity . 
My code is MainPage.java

```
 public void onResponse(String response) {

                System.out.println("output -- "+response);
                members = response;
                Intent intn = new Intent(MainPage.this,Calculation.class);
                intn.putExtra("MEMBERS",members);

            }
```

I am getting the correct response .

Calculation.java

```
Intent intn = new Intent();
        members = intn.getStringExtra("MEMBERS");
        System.out.println("dmkmdk"+members);
        //no_of_members = Integer.parseInt(members);
```

I also want to parse it in integer form .

Comment: You are missing `startActivity` in first snippet . and Use `getIntent().getStringExtra("MEMBERS");` in next one .

Comment: but I don't want to start a new activity . I just want to pass the value

Comment: Then you should edit your question . In this case your code is useless . Use a `Broadcastreceiver` instead or `startActivityForResult`.

Comment: we just have to pass the value from one activity to another bu we are getting null we dont have to start the activity we just have to use that variable "member" in other activity......

Answer (score 0):

you should get extra like this, don't initiate an intent object

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String value1 = extras.getString("MEMBERS");
```

Comment: Still getting null in the next activity . The response which I am getting is a single value only

Comment: you should add startActivity(intent); in the first class to send the data to the second activity

Answer (score 0):

Try to save data in SharedPreference instead Intent.

```
SharedPreferences pref = 
getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); // 0 - for private mode
Editor editor = pref.edit();
```

For Storing data:-

```
editor.putString("MEMBERS",members);
editor.apply();
```

For retriving data:-

```
editor.getString("MEMBERS", null); // getting String
```

Comment: we just have to pass the value from one activity to another but we are getting null we just have to use that variable "member" in other activity.without using shared preference is there any other solution

Comment: make a one class in which create a variable and when your onResume returns result assign it to that variable and access on another activity.

Comment: can you make it more clear plz ? can u please give one demo example?

Comment: refer this:-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878159/whats-the-best-way-to-share-data-between-activities

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

To Transfer data in next activity

```
public void onResponse(String response) {

                    System.out.println("output -- "+response);
                    members = response;
                    Intent intn = new Intent(MainPage.this,Calculation.class);
                    intn.putExtra("MEMBERS",members);
    startActivity(intn)

                }
```

In New activity where you want to get data try this line

```
String resFromLast = getIntent().getExtras().getString("MEMBERS");
Log.e("Response From last activity is :" ,resFromLast);
```

MEMBERS is that key you passed in last activity with intent.

Hope it works.