# How to pass arraylist from MainActivity to display listview to Main2Activity?

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have have 2 activities "MainActivity", "Main2Activity" and 2 classes "User", "UserAdapter". What I want actually want is explained below.

1. First of all I want to insert several data from "MainActivity" (If I insert "name" and "email" 5 times then I've inserted 5 data) by clicking "submit" button.
2. Then I want to show all data as listview in "Main2Activity" which is another activity.
3. But I can only see the last data I've inserted while I inserted several data.
4. I mean if I insert 1st data(John, john123@gmail.com), 2nd data(cherry, cherry45@gmail.com) by clicking submit button I can see all data in same activity which is "MainActivity" and can only see the last data (cherry, cherry45@gmail.com) in second activity which is "Main2Activity".
5. Can anyone help me to pass entire arraylist from MainActivity to display in listview to Main2Activity? My all codes are given below.

===============MainActivity.java=================

```
package com.andromet.customlistview;

import android.content.Intent;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;`

import android.view.View;

import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

import android.widget.EditText;

import android.widget.ListView;

import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.Serializable;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText editName, editEmail;
String name, email;
Intent intent;
UserAdapter adapter;

ListView listView;
ArrayList<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    editName = findViewById(R.id.name);
    editEmail = findViewById(R.id.email);
    listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
    adapter = new UserAdapter(this, users);
}

public void submit(View view) {
    name = editName.getText().toString();
    email = editEmail.getText().toString();

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    users.add(new User(name,email));
    intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);

    intent.putExtra("name", name);
    intent.putExtra("email", email);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    Toast.makeText(this,"Total Items: " +users.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public void onListClicked(View view) {
    //intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

===============Main2Activity.java================

```
package com.andromet.customlistview;

import android.content.Intent;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.widget.ListView;

import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView listView;
UserAdapter adapter;
String name, email;
ArrayList<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    listView = findViewById(R.id.listView2);
    adapter = new UserAdapter(this, users);
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    name = bundle.getString("name");
    email = bundle.getString("email");

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    users.add(new User(name, email));
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    Toast.makeText(this,"Total Items: " +users.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

}
```

==================User.java=================

```
package com.andromet.customlistview;

public class User {

private String name;
private String email;

public User(String name, String email) {
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String emial) {
    this.email = emial;
}

}
```

===============UserAdapter.java=================

```
package com.andromet.customlistview;

import android.content.Context;

import android.support.annotation.NonNull;

import android.support.annotation.Nullable;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;

import android.view.View;

import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class UserAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<User> {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<User> users;

public UserAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<User> users){
    super(context, 0, users);
    this.users = users;
    this.context = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;

    if (row == null){
        row = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.mylist,parent,false);
    }
    User user = users.get(position);

    if (row != null){
        TextView textViewName = row.findViewById(R.id.view_name);
        TextView textViewEmail = row.findViewById(R.id.view_email);
        textViewName.setText(user.getName());
        textViewEmail.setText(user.getEmail());
    }

    return row;
}
}
```

[This is what I can see in Main2Activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14VWV.jpg)

[This is what I can see in MainActivity and I want to pass this entire array to Main2Activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRAJB.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878159/whats-the-best-way-to-share-data-between-activities. Review the singleton and other options in the accepted answer there as ways of storing and sharing data between activities.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of problems in Your implementation.

1. You are not saving `User` data anywhere like in some class other than your activities.
2. You are not passing all the data to `Main2Activity`, that why You can see only one item and that's also the latest added item.

Solution:

1. Save User data in some `UserManager` class. You can make this class `Singleton` for ease of access. Provide the method to add User into some `ArrayList` and a get method to retrieve the whole list.
2. Now, whenever Your `Main2Activity` start, fetch data from `UserManager` and then display it in the list.

Comment: I have no idea how to implement UserManager to save and fetch data from it. I have given all my source code. Can you please cooperate to come to this solution providing "UserManager" class implemented and necessary source codes to add to the Main2Activity class?

Comment: something like this http://www.java2novice.com/java_constructor_examples/singleton/

Comment: Although I solved this problem in alternative way, thanks for your extreme help. I have solved this using string array. It does save data temporarily till running the app. But this time I am happy with that. :)