# Using Multiple intents to pass data in activities not working

Tags: android, android-intent, android-recyclerview

I would like to pass data between activities. When I use one activity (Details), everything works fine, but when I add a second activity (MapsActivity), the application ignores (Details) and transfers data only to MapsActivity. How can I fix it? Thanks  in advance

```
 holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        Intent mIntent = new Intent(context, Details.class);
        Intent mapIntent= new Intent(context,MapsActivity.class);
        mIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        mapIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);


        mIntent.putExtra("Country_CurrencyCode", pozycja.getCurrencies().get(0).getCode());
        mIntent.putExtra("Country_CurrencyName", pozycja.getCurrencies().get(0).getName());
        mIntent.putExtra("Country_CurrencySymbol", pozycja.getCurrencies().get(0).getSymbol());

        context.startActivity(mIntent);

        mapIntent.putExtra("Country_Lat",pozycja.getLatlng().get(0));
        mapIntent.putExtra("Country_Lng",pozycja.getLatlng().get(1));

        context.startActivity(mapIntent);
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve.

Comment: I would like to pass data to Details.class and MapsActivity.class

Comment: And why you are starting two activities at the same time?

Comment: Why do you use `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`?

Comment: Given that you can only show one activity at a time, this seems like you are just trying to make a workaround to make some data persistent across multiple Activities. I'd suggest reading different options [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878159/whats-the-best-way-to-share-data-between-activities) and looking into different ways of sharing/storing data between multiple activities. Seems like using SharedPreferences would work a lot better in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a behavior I did not expect but after testing your code, I found these:  
You start 1st the `Details` activity and 2nd the `MapsActivity`.  
The result is that you see on the screen the 2nd activity: `MapsActivity`.   
For this activity you can check that it's got all the extra values that you passed.  
What is happening is that although you have also started the 1st activity: `Details`, its `onCreate()` has not yet been invoked, but it will be invoked as soon as you close the 2nd activity `MapsActivity` and then you will see that its extras are there as you put them.  
 So the 1st activity gets the extras fine but until its `onCreate()` is called you can't access them.    
So **a workaround**:    
Start only `Details` activity but pass to it not only its own extras but `MapsActivity`'s extras also.   
In Details's `onCreate()` start `MapsActivity` with 
its own extras.

Comment: @smitzervojtech you know with your problem I learned something too, so thank you!