# How to transfer data from one time open activity to next

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I am new to android!.
I have made spinner in activity 1 (one time open Activity) and want to transfer selected value from spinner  by user to activity 2.I have used sharedPreference for one time open activity .Its only working 1st time but second time it cant transfer data.I am stuck here please help me

```
    SharedPreferences Preferences=getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE",MODE_PRIVATE);
    String FirstTime=Preferences.getString("FirstTimeInstall","");


       button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String parent=sp_parent.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String child=sp_child.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String college=sp_college.getSelectedItem().toString();

            Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Dashboard.class);
            intent.putExtra("parent",parent);
            intent.putExtra("child",child);
            intent.putExtra("college",college);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();


        }
    });


            if (FirstTime.equals("Yes")){
            String parent=sp_parent.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String child=sp_child.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String college=sp_college.getSelectedItem().toString();

        Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Dashboard.class);
            intent.putExtra("parent",parent);
            intent.putExtra("child",child);
            intent.putExtra("college",college);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();


    }else {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=Preferences.edit();
        editor.putString("FirstTimeInstall","Yes");
        editor.apply();
    }
```

Comment: Have a look at this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application

Comment: i know intent method but in one time activity the data is transfer only first time

Comment: get value from SharedPreferences in second activity, if is it defaultValue, get it from intent that received from first activity. what's the problem?

Comment: There are multiple ways, you can create your data holder class. and reference it from different activities for shared data. have a look here for multiple ways https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878159/whats-the-best-way-to-share-data-between-activities

Comment: Intent used in shared preference is not taking value from activity1 .Its directly jumping to activity 2

Answer (score 1):

When starting a new activity you can send data through intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent( this, Activity2.class );
intent.putExtra( "key", "value" );
startActivity(intent)
```

And in second activity do like this:

```
getIntent().getStringExtra( "key" );
```

or if you are sending int for example

```
getIntent().getIntExtra( "key", 0 );
```