# How can I pass object from ArrayList to new Activity and then receive that?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, arraylist, parcelable

I try pass an object to new activity but I have a problem. My ArrayList use another class in this way:

```
ArrayList<ListData> myList = new ArrayList<>();
```

All is great, I'm adding to mList a few objects and my listview work fine.
I try pass an object after click in this way:

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

            ListData listdata = myList.get(position);

            ListData dataToSend = new ListData();
            dataToSend.setStrefa(listdata.getStrefa());
            dataToSend.setDzielnica(listdata.getDzielnica());
            dataToSend.setAdres(listdata.getAdres());
            dataToSend.setKryteria(listdata.getKryteria());
            dataToSend.setTelefon(listdata.getTelefon());
            dataToSend.setData(listdata.getData());

            Intent intent = new Intent(Zlecenia.this, Zlecenie.class);
            intent.putExtra("myData", dataToSend);
            startActivity(intent);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.no_animation);

      }

  });
```

Here is a problem because "bundle.putParcelableArrayList("listdata", listdata);" is marked on red. This forces on me using extends Parcelable in ListData Class but when I added this extends then my ArrayList is empty. What schould I do?

My ListData:

```
public class ListData implements Parcelable{

    String Strefa;
    String Adres;
    String Kryteria;
    String Telefon;
    String Data;
    String Dzielnica;
    String Ilosc;

    /* Zlecenia */

    public String getStrefa() {
        return Strefa;
    }

    public void setStrefa(String strefa) {
        this.Strefa = strefa;
    }

    public String getAdres() {
        return Adres;
    }

    public void setAdres(String adres) {
        this.Adres = adres;
    }

    public String getKryteria() {
        return Kryteria;
    }

    public void setKryteria(String kryteria) {
        this.Kryteria = kryteria;
    }

    public String getTelefon() {
        return Telefon;
    }

    public void setTelefon(String telefon) {
        this.Telefon = telefon;
    }

    public String getData() {
        return Data;
    }

    public void setData(String data) {
        this.Data = data;
    }

    /* Statystyki */

    public String getDzielnica() {
        return Dzielnica;
    }

    public void setDzielnica(String dzielnica) {
        this.Dzielnica = dzielnica;
    }

    public String getIlosc() {
        return Ilosc;
    }

    public void setIlosc(String ilosc) {
        this.Ilosc = ilosc;
    }


    public ListData() {

    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

        dest.writeString(Strefa);
        dest.writeString(Dzielnica);
        dest.writeString(Adres);
        dest.writeString(Kryteria);
        dest.writeString(Telefon);
        dest.writeString(Data);

    }

    private ListData(Parcel in) {

        Strefa = in.readString();
        Dzielnica = in.readString();
        Adres = in.readString();
        Kryteria = in.readString();
        Telefon = in.readString();
        Data = in.readString();

    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<ListData> CREATOR
            = new Parcelable.Creator<ListData>() {

        @Override
        public ListData createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new ListData(in);
        }

        @Override
        public ListData[] newArray(int size) {
            return new ListData[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Can you show ListData also.

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-parcelable

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6681784/1044554 this might help explain it better for you

Comment: I created a MyParcelable class. How can I pass to this class listdata object of ListData? I don't understand.

Comment: OK, I worked it out but I read in WEB on Parcelable and now I don't know what is better. Whether use common putExtra("name", value); or Parcelable. I must pass a few item from my listview based on baseAdapter. This code is works but please tell what is better.

Answer (score 2):

Try this in your class

```
public class ListData implements Serializable
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, consider explaining to OP why he should try it.

Comment: I read that Parcelable is faster so I would like use just this solution.

Comment: http://prasanta-paul.blogspot.com.br/2010/06/android-parcelable-example.html