# Show the data on the next activity

Tags: java, android, json, listview

this show the data on the listview on the same activity but i want to show the data on the second activity how i can pass the JSON object to the other Class.

This is the code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    public static final String DATA_URL = ;   public static final String KEY_NAME = "Name";
    public static final String KEY_CITY = "City";
    public static final String KEY_AGE = "Age";
    public static final String KEY_GENDER = "Gender";
    public static final String KEY_ADDRESS = "Address";
    public static final String KEY_BLOOD = "Blood_Group";
    public static final String KEY_CONTACT = "contact_no";
    public static final String JSON_ARRAY = "result";

    private EditText editText;
    private Button buttonGet;
    ListView list;

    private ProgressDialog loading;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        buttonGet = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonGet);
        buttonGet.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private void getData() {
        String b = editText.getText().toString().trim();
        if (b.equals("")) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        loading = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Please wait...","Fetching...",false,false);

        String url = DATA_URL+editText.getText().toString().trim();

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    loading.dismiss();
                    showJSON(response);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,error.getMessage().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
        });

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    private void showJSON(String response){
        String[] Name;
        String[] Blood_Group;
        String[] Gender;
        String[] contact_no;
        String[] City;
        String[] Age;
        String[] Address;

        int i;
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
            JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(JSON_ARRAY);
            Name = new String[result.length()];
            Blood_Group = new String[result.length()];
            Address = new String[result.length()];
            City = new String[result.length()];
            contact_no = new String[result.length()];
            Age = new String[result.length()];
            Gender = new String[result.length()];

            for(i = 0 ; i< result.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject employee_data = result.getJSONObject(i);
                Blood_Group[i] = employee_data.getString(KEY_BLOOD);
                Name[i] = employee_data.getString(KEY_NAME);
                contact_no[i] = employee_data.getString(KEY_CONTACT);
                Address[i]= employee_data.getString(KEY_ADDRESS);
                Age[i] = employee_data.getString(KEY_AGE);
                Gender[i] = employee_data.getString(KEY_GENDER);
                City[i]= employee_data.getString(KEY_CITY);

                ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
                CustomList cl = new CustomList(this, Name ,Blood_Group,City,contact_no,Address,Age,Gender);
                list.setAdapter(cl);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Sorry",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        Toast.makeText(this,"Show",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        getData();
    }
}
```

Custom LIST.java

```
public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private Activity context;

    private String[] Name;
    private String[] Blood_Group;
    private String[] Gender;
    private String[] contact_no;
    private String[] City;
    private String[] Age;
    private String[] Address;

    public CustomList(Activity context, String[] Name, String[] Blood_Group, String[] Gender, String[] contant_no, String[] City, String[] Address, String[] Age) {

        super(context, R.layout.list_item, Blood_Group);
        this.context = context;
        this.Name = Name;
        this.Blood_Group = Blood_Group;
        this.Age = Age;
        this.City = City;
        this.contact_no = contant_no;
        this.Gender = Gender;
        this.Address =Address;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

        View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null, true);

        TextView textViewName = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.tvListname);
        TextView textViewAge = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.tvListage);
        TextView textViewBlood = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.tvListbloodgroup);
        TextView textViewGender = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.tvListgender);
        TextView textViewContact_No = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.tvListcontact);
        TextView textViewCity = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.tvListcity);
        TextView textViewAddress = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.tvListaddress);

        textViewName.setText("Name"+Name[position]);
        textViewAge.setText(Age[position]);
        textViewBlood.setText(Blood_Group[position]);
        textViewGender.setText(Gender[position]);
        textViewContact_No.setText(contact_no[position]);
        textViewCity.setText(City[position]);
        textViewAddress.setText(Address[position]);

        return listViewItem;
    }
}
```

Comment: This has solution here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748444/passing-strings-between-activities-in-android

Comment: Visit: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Help passing an ArrayList of Objects to a new Activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6681217/help-passing-an-arraylist-of-objects-to-a-new-activity)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a string from your JSON object and pass the string through the intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,DetailedActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("json",jsonObject.toString());
                startActivity(intent);
```

On the detailed activity u can extract the string from intent extra and create a JSON object from that string as follows

```
        String fromIntentExtra = getIntent().getStringExtra("json");
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(intentExtra);
```

This will fullfill your purpose but this is not a good paractice

Comment: Your English is alright, but this answer could be improved upon with some example code, rather than a link.

Comment: check out my new answer please. and there are a lot of question and solution similar to this problem. you should go through them before asking