# Pass ArrayList Class Object to another fragment using Bundle in Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, arraylist, bundle

I need to pass ArrayList of class object to another fragment using Bundle.

I have tried this something like this from this [post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6681217/help-passing-an-arraylist-of-objects-to-a-new-activity)

```
List< SubCateogory > subCatList = allLists.getResult().getCategory().get(position).getSubCategories();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putParcelableArray(ApplicationVariables.SUB_CAT_LISTS, subCatList);
```

It displays following error. `Wrong 2nd argument type. Found: 'java.util.List<com.healthcamp.healthapp.models.HomeCategory.SubCateogory>', required: 'android.os.Parcelable[]'`

My Category, SubCategory classes implements `Parceable` along with required methods for parceable.

**Result.java**

```
public class Results implements Parcelable {

@SerializedName("category")
@Expose
private List<Category> category = null;

public List<Category> getCategory() {
    return category;
}

public void setCategory(List<Category> category) {
    this.category = category;
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

}
}
```

**Category.java**

```
public class Category implements Parcelable { ...
```

**SubCategory.java**

```
public class SubCateogory implements Parcelable {...
```

Please suggest. Thank You.

Comment: Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/q/7042272/6134394

Comment: Do not post screenshots of code, copy/paste the code into your post.

Comment: Did you understand the meaning of `required: 'android.os.Parcelable[]`? It wants an _array_ of `Parcelable` objects, not a list.

Comment: @JimGarrison Ok. I removed the screenshot. Yes as suggested by @hacksy, used `putParcelableArrayList` and it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `putParcelableArrayList` instead of `putParcelableArray`

Also , you need to define your instance as an `ArrayList` so change it to
 `ArrayList< SubCateogory > subCatList`