# parse arraylist form one fragment to another fragment in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, arraylist

How I can parse Arraylist of JSON from one Fragment to another fragment here is my arraylist code where I am getting arraylist from my model:

```
private void setListOffers(JSONArray categoryArray) {
    for (int i = 0; i < categoryArray.length(); i++) {
        try {
            JSONObject object = categoryArray.getJSONObject(i);
            hotDealID = object.getInt("ID");
            deals.add(new ListOffers(hotDealID));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here I am sending data from fraggment:

```
private ArrayList<ListOffers> deals = new ArrayList<>();
Fragment fragment = new HotDealFragment();
Bundle  bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putParcelableArrayList("dealsId", deals);
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

When I put this code then deals gives exception that wrong second argument and `ListOffers` is my model where I am fetching data

and here is my model list Offers:

```
private int Id;

public ListOffers(int Id){
    this.Id = Id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    Id = id;
}

public int getId() {
    return Id;
}
```

Comment: Did you implement Parcelable for your ListOffers class?

Comment: no I have not implemented it

Comment: So implement Parcelable in your ListOffers class and you will not get exception.

Answer (score 1):

One possible problem:

Your ListOffers model does not implement parcelable. Your model should implement parcelable. You can get help from this link

https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-Parcelable

```
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class ListOffers implements Parcelable {

private int Id;

public ListOffers(int Id) {
    this.Id = Id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    Id = id;
}

public int getId() {
    return Id;
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeInt(Id);
}

protected ListOffers(Parcel in) {

    Id = in.readInt();
}

public static final Creator<ListOffers> CREATOR = new Creator<ListOffers>() {

    @Override
    public ListOffers createFromParcel(Parcel in) {

        return new ListOffers(in);
    }

    @Override
    public ListOffers[] newArray(int size) {

        return new ListOffers[size];
    }
};
}
```

Comment: my Model is:public ListOffers(int Id){
        this.Id = Id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        Id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return Id;
    }

Comment: @ansarabbas Update your question with your model code.

Comment: I am also populating my model to arraylist deal. set my updated question

Comment: @ansarabbas Update your question with your model ListOffers

Answer (score 1):

**Using hashmap you can pass**

```
HashMap <String,ArrayList<ListOffers>> hashMap;
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putSerializable("HashMap",hashMap);
intent.putExtras(extras);
```

**And get it using below code**

```
Intent intent = getIntent();    
hasMap= intent.getSerializableExtra("hashMap");
```

Answer (score 0):

your datamodel ListOffers should be implement the Parcelable then only you can pass as ParcelableArrayList.

refer

[Help passing an ArrayList of Objects to a new Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6681217/help-passing-an-arraylist-of-objects-to-a-new-activity)

Answer (score 0):

Using [Parcelable](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidParcelable/article.html) your model will be

```
public class ListOffers implements Parcelable {

    private int Id;

    /**
     * Constructs a Model from a Parcel
     *
     * @param parcel Source Parcel
     */
    public ListOffers(Parcel parcel) {
        this.Id = parcel.readInt();
    }

    public ListOffers(int Id) {
        this.Id = Id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        Id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
        parcel.writeInt(Id);
    }

    // Method to recreate a Model from a Parcel
    public static Creator<ListOffers> CREATOR = new Creator<ListOffers>() {

        @Override
        public ListOffers createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new ListOffers(source);
        }

        @Override
        public ListOffers[] newArray(int size) {
            return new ListOffers[size];
        }

    };
}
```

Sending `ParcelableArrayList` from one fragment to other -

```
private ArrayList<ListOffers> deals = new ArrayList<>();
setListOffers(categoryArray);
Fragment fragment = new HotDealFragment();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putParcelableArrayList("dealsId", deals);
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

Fetching it into other `Fragment` in it's `onCreate` -

```
ArrayList<ListOffers> deals = new ArrayList<>();
if (getArguments() != null) {
    deals = getArguments().getParcelableArrayList("dealsId");
}
```

Hope this will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easier approach.

Most times when one wants to send this data is because they want it to be accessed in the new class for just a short time. Instead of sending the data every time, go to the fragment that contains the data and make it public and static.

```
public static ArrayList<ListOffers> deals;
```

Access it in your desired activity

```
MainFragment.deals
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your ListOffer implements Serializable and then use

```
private ArrayList<ListOffers> deals = new ArrayList<>();
Fragment fragment = new HotDealFragment();
    Bundle  bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putSerializable("dealsId", deals);
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

Here is how to get that

```
if (getArguments() != null)  {
       mdealsId = (ListOffers)getArguments().getSerializable("dealsId");
 }
```