# how to pass stringarraylist values from one class to another class in android

Tags: android, android-layout

hi i would like to send string arraylist values from one class another class.i tried using bundle concept but in second class in arraylist showing null value.plaese any one suggest me wherre did mistake..

```
  Activity1.class:
 public static ArrayList<String> customers = new ArrayList<String>();
        customers.add("radha");
        customers.add("aswini");
           Intent i=new Intent(Activity1 .this,Activity2.class);
         i.putExtra("customers1", customers);
        Log.i("arrayvalues1",""+ customers);
        startActivity(i);

     Activity2.class:
     String[] mystringArray = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("customers1");
    Log.i("arrayvalues2",""+ mystringArray);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ArrayList<String> mystringArray = getintent().getStringArrayListExtra("customers1");
```

Answer (score 0):

when the arraylist is public static, you can directly access it using classname.arraylist na.

Activity1.cutomers

Comment: read above two answer..that will be helpful..Dont use static cause that's not reliable,creates memory leaks..also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475978/using-static-variables-in-android

Comment: hmm...yeah, otherwise its too obvious :P

Comment: yes it it obvious :)..that developer use it..but going through documentation and good blogs..you will find that Static can make how much trouble for you..

Comment: hi,sory.in Avtivity2 i use Activity1.customers=customers1; but in  customers1 null value is there.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a public static variable, you can access it in a static way:

In Activity2.class:

Activity1.customers;

Comment: sory.but Activity1.customers=customers1; i use like this,but in  customers1 null value is there

Comment: Sorry but that doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

For Activity 1:

```
 ArrayList<String> Customers = new ArrayList<String>();
 Intent i=new Intent(Activity1 .this,Activity2.class);
 i.putStringArrayListExtra("customers1",(ArrayList<String>) Customers);         
 startActivity(i);
```

For Activity 2:

```
 ArrayList<String> Customers = new ArrayList<String>();
 Bundle extra=getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extra!=null){
        Customers =extra.getStringArrayList("customers1");  
    }
```