# Pass form data to the called activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

How do i get all the user input fields from *signupActivity* which is currently taking email, passwords and rest of the fields as input from the user and use it in *finalactivity*.

I already have made the xml layout and wonder how can i display all these fields to a newer activity which is called when signup button is pressed.

My SignupActivity.java:-

```
public class SignupActivity extends AppCompatActivity {    
    @Bind(R.id.input_name) EditText _nameText;
    @Bind(R.id.input_email) EditText _emailText;
    @Bind(R.id.input_password) EditText _passwordText;
    @Bind(R.id.btn_signup) Button _signupButton;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signing);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        _signupButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                  signup();
            }
        });
    }
    public void signup(){
        //call the finalactivity and do the 
    }
}
```

And now finally the **signup()** function should call the activity *finalActivity* and print the info. Maybe like this-
For eg in the *finalactivity* i want to display-

> Your name is :"name here" 
>   
>   And your email is :"email here"

My question is different from [How do I pass data between Activities in Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application) as i want to pass multiple variables (~50) and obviously dont want to create 50 Intents.

Comment: @SatanPandeya That helped but i need to pass multiple variables not just a single one. Do I have to create new Intents For every new variable i want to pass?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13601883/how-to-pass-arraylist-of-objects-from-one-to-another-activity-using-intent-in-an
This is what u r lokin 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to solve this problem is using Intent.

pass the required data from SignUp Activity to finalActivity using Intent

```
public void signup(){
    Intent intent  = new Intent(SignUp.this,finalactivity.class );
    intent.putExtra("name", name);//name you get from EditText
    intent.putExtra("email", email);//emailyou get from EditText
    startActivity( intent );  
}
```

In finalactivity, in OnCreate() method do this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.final_activity);

    name=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    email=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    String name_v=getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
    String email_v=getIntent().getStringExtra("email");
    name.setText(name_v);
    pass.setText(email_v);


}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Well thanks a lot but is there a more convenient way? I mean do i have to create a new intent every time? Say i need to pass 100 variables .... Something like an array-intent stuff???

Comment: yeah you can pass arraylist through Intent

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13601883/how-to-pass-arraylist-of-objects-from-one-to-another-activity-using-intent-in-an    look into this

Comment: Well it did it.  Thanks a lot. Pls update your answer so that others can follow. Marking it accepted now.

Answer (score 0):

In your current Activity, pass the result via `Intent`:

```
Intent i = new Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
i.putExtra("NAME_KEY", "NAME_VALUE");
i.putExtra("EMAIL_KEY", "EMAIL_VALUE");
i.putExtra("PASSWORD_KEY", "PASSWORD_VALUE");
startActivity(i);
```

Retrieve the result from another Activity:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        String name = extras.getString("NAME_KEY");
        String email = extras.getString("EMAIL_KEY");
        String password = extras.getString("PASSWORD_KEY");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<Object> object = new ArrayList<Object>();
Intent intent = new Intent(Current.class, Transfer.class);
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putSerializable("ARRAYLIST",(Serializable)object);
intent.putExtra("BUNDLE",args);
startActivity(intent);
```

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle args = intent.getBundleExtra("BUNDLE");
ArrayList<Object> object = (ArrayList<Object>) args.getSerializable("ARRAYLIST");
```

This would do probably.
[How to pass ArrayList of Objects from one to another activity using Intent in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13601883/how-to-pass-arraylist-of-objects-from-one-to-another-activity-using-intent-in-an) --source

Comment: Ya it did. I already have an answer though. Thanks.