# Transfer images from one activity to GalleryActivity

Tags: android, android-gallery

I have an activity where I show a viewpager with a few Images. These images are retrieved from a remote source using Glide.

Now i want that when the user clicks on an image, he/she is taken to a GalleryActivity where they can also swipe to see the rest of pictures.

How can I make it so these images are transferred to the GalleryActivity and not need to be downloaded again?

Comment: post your code here please

Comment: you just add photos URL in an array and pass this to next Activity. Glide automatically cache these images.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to worry about that, glide cache your images, it will not download again if url is same.

> The default strategy, AUTOMATIC, tries to use the optimal strategy for
>   local and remote images. AUTOMATIC will store only the unmodified data
>   backing your load when you’re loading remote data (like from URLs)
>   because downloading remote data is expensive compared to resizing data
>   already on disk. For local data AUTOMATIC will store the transformed
>   thumbnail only because retrieving the original data is cheap if you
>   need to generate a second thumbnail size or type.

You can see [Glide Caching](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/caching.html).

So just pass your image url array to next activity. and load with glide. See [How to pass array to next activity](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3848148/6891563).

Comment: Question is different though

Comment: Let PO decide please.

Comment: It's not only OP dependent. If it is posted it is for the community too

Comment: @VivekMishra He wanted to pass image, just not to download again, so I make him aware about caching from glide. If he know that glide cache automatically, then he will not be worried about to pass some downloaded image, he need to pass only urls array.

Answer (score 0):

Make an `ArrayList` of files/paths/Uris in your activity and pass the image array to another activity as extras.

```
intent.putExtra("images", yourList);
```

Then you can receive the list from the key `"images"` in the `GalleryActivity`.

You can also pass the index of the current Image so that you can set the default position in the `ViewPager`.

Comment: Model should be Parcelable/Serializable.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/13601883/6891563

Comment: @Khemraj, ArrayList/File/Uri/String all are either `Parcelable` or `Serializable` or both.

Comment: I just added ref, user may need it to pass his model arraylist.