# How to pass ArrayList<Fragment>?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, arraylist

To avoid creating multiple activities I have one **Activity2** that has this code that allows me to just pass an array of Fragments from any Activity I want.

```
privateArrayList<Fragment> fragArrayList;

fragArrayList = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("fragArrayList");

Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          setFragment(fragArrayList.get(i));
        }
    });

private void setFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    manager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.layout, fragment)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
}
```

In **Activity1** I have this code (That I know doesn't work)

```
Wrong 2nd argument type. Found: 'java.util.ArrayList<android.support.v4.app.Fragment>', required: 'java.util.ArrayList<? extends android.os.Parcelable>'
```

.

```
Intent intent= new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);

ArrayList<Fragment> fragArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
                fragArrayList.add(new frag1());
                fragArrayList.add(new frag2());
                fragArrayList.add(new frag3());
                fragArrayList.add(new frag4());
                fragArrayList.add(new frag5());

                intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("fragArrayList"), fragArrayList);
```

The point is to make fragArrayList travel from **any** Activity to **Activity2**. And since the frags inside fragArrayList will be different depending on the activity they are coming from I cant just add them to the ArrayList inside **Activity2**.

And since there will be several activities is not efficient to create logic inside the **Activity2** to handle from each Activity the user came from.

***How can I pass the ArrayList from Activity1 to Activity2?***

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13601883/how-to-pass-arraylist-of-objects-from-one-to-another-activity-using-intent-in-an/24630640

Comment: follow this link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Success** Thank you to: **[Greg Moens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10630172/greg-moens)** & **[gicci](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1180091/gicci)** for the insight

**Activity1**

```
Intent intent= new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);

ArrayList<String> fragArrayList= new ArrayList<>();

fragArrayList.add(String.valueOf(frag1.class.getName()));
fragArrayList.add(String.valueOf(frag2.class.getName()));
fragArrayList.add(String.valueOf(frag3.class.getName()));
fragArrayList.add(String.valueOf(frag4.class.getName()));
fragArrayList.add(String.valueOf(frag5.class.getName()));

intent.putExtra("fragArrayList"), fragArrayList);
```

**Activity2**

```
ArrayList<String> fragArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

fragArrayList = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("fragArrayList");

Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      setFragment(fragArrayList.get(i));
    }
});

 private void setFragment(String fragClass) {

    Fragment fragment = Fragment.instantiate(this, fragClass);

    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    manager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.layout, fragment)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Fragments are not Parcelable, so you won't be able to pass them via intent. You could pass the fully qualified fragment class name via intent and then instantiate the fragment(s) in Activity2 via reflection.

Comment: You can also build an ArrayList of Class objects, which are serializable, then use putExtra(name, arrayList), recover them with getSerializable(name), and then build the fragments with reflection directly from the class object with newInstance().

Comment: Thank you for your answers I did it!

Answer (score 0):

That's a bad design passing list of fragment objects and you could only pass array of Parcelable class of object.