# Passing arraylist of objects between activities

Tags: android, android-intent, arraylist, android-activity, parcelable

I am trying to pass an arraylist of objects between two activities, but my app crushes at the second activity. Can someone help me solve this problem...

Here is my code from my first activity:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putParcelableArrayList("songs",(ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) albumsArray.get(position).getSongs());
Log.v("--", "OK");
i.putExtras(b);
i.setClass(LatestAlbums.this, AlbumDetails.class);
startActivity(i);
```

And code from the second activity:

```
songs=new ArrayList<Songs>();
Bundle b = this.getIntent().getExtras();
if(b!=null)
    songs = b.getParcelable("songs");
Log.v("--", songs.size()+"");
```

And my logcat output:

```
04-03 16:37:03.513: E/AndroidRuntime(6576): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-03 16:37:03.513: E/AndroidRuntime(6576): java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value com.musicapp.objects.Songs@419489e8
04-03 16:37:03.513: E/AndroidRuntime(6576):     at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1137)
04-03 16:37:03.513: E/AndroidRuntime(6576):     at android.os.Parcel.writeList(Parcel.java:524)
04-03 16:37:03.513: E/AndroidRuntime(6576):     at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1097)
04-03 16:37:03.513: E/AndroidRuntime(6576):     at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:493)
04-03 16:37:03.513: E/AndroidRuntime(6576):     at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1612)
04-03 16:37:03.513: E/AndroidRuntime(6576):     at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:507)
04-03 16:37:03.513: E/AndroidRuntime(6576):     at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:6147)
04-03 16:37:03.513: E/AndroidRuntime(6576):     at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:1613)
04-03 16:37:03.513: E/AndroidRuntime(6576):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1379)
04-03 16:37:03.513: E/AndroidRuntime(6576):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityFromChild(Activity.java:3458)
04-03 16:37:03.513: E/AndroidRuntime(6576):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3210)
04-03 16:37:03.513: E/AndroidRuntime(6576):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:817)
04-03 16:37:03.513: E/AndroidRuntime(6576):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3297)
04-03 16:37:03.513: E/AndroidRuntime(6576):     at com.outsourcefarm.musicagratis.activities.LatestAlbums$4$1.onItemClick(LatestAlbums.java:232)
04-03 16:37:03.513: E/AndroidRuntime(6576):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:292)
04-03 16:37:03.513: E/AndroidRuntime(6576):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1058)
04-03 16:37:03.513: E/AndroidRuntime(6576):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2514)
04-03 16:37:03.513: E/AndroidRuntime(6576):     at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3168)
04-03 16:37:03.513: E/AndroidRuntime(6576):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
04-03 16:37:03.513: E/AndroidRuntime(6576):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-03 16:37:03.513: E/AndroidRuntime(6576):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-03 16:37:03.513: E/AndroidRuntime(6576):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4440)
04-03 16:37:03.513: E/AndroidRuntime(6576):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-03 16:37:03.513: E/AndroidRuntime(6576):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-03 16:37:03.513: E/AndroidRuntime(6576):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
04-03 16:37:03.513: E/AndroidRuntime(6576):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
04-03 16:37:03.513: E/AndroidRuntime(6576):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: does your `Song` object implement `Parcelable`?

Comment: @OvidiuLatcu no. How can I implement that?

Comment: `public class Song implements Parcelable {...}` . http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html

Comment: @OvidiuLatcu yes that is the answer. Could you post your answer for me to accept it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should make your `Song` class  implement [`Parcelable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html).

Answer (score 22):

You try the below

```
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("key", ArrayList<T extends Parcelable> list);
startActivity(intent);
```

Retrieve it

```
getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("key");
```

[Pass arraylist of user defined objects to Intent android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15747727/pass-arraylist-of-user-defined-objects-to-intent-android/15747819#). Check the answer by Sajmon

According to the comments made by Sajmon, `Song` class has to `implement` `Parcelable`

Comment: yes this works :} but most likely author's `Song` class does not implement `Parcelable`.

Comment: @Sajmon the wrapping arraylist that you suggested for another question does not work in this case?

Comment: Raghunandan it works this what i wrote: `ArrayList<T extends Parcelable> list` i wrote it "generally" `-->` second paramater of `putParcelableArrayListExtra()` must be `ArrayList<T>` where `T` implements `Parcelable` so it works for sure also for `ArrayList<Song>` but `Song` class must implements `Parcelable` interface.

Comment: So Song class has to implement 'Parcelable'

Comment: Can I pass arrayList like you do in Java(by using objects )?

Comment: @Amit0191 you mean list of objects. Yes you can do that provided you have your model class implements Parcelable.

Comment: No I didn't mean list of Objects.

Comment: @Raghunandan Can I pass ArrayList (between activities)like we do between two classes(Class A has arrayList. Create an instance in Class B of class A and use it to access the arrayList)?

What about if one class is activity and the other is not?
Thank you.

Comment: @Amit0191 you can pass arraylist between activities cause arraylist implements serializable. You should never create an instance of activity class. You only declare it in manifest. its the job of android to do that.

Answer (score 8):

```
Intent intent=new Intent(ActivityFrom.this,ActivityTo.class);
intent.putExtra("StringKey",arrayList);
startActivity(intent);
```

and to retrieve

```
ArrayList<String> myList = (ArrayList<String>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("StringKey");
```

Comment: Thank you for response, In order to pass String array this is a easiest method i found, if you have better one please post that Mr. Vinil Chandran(sir)

Comment: First of all the question is about object not the string. For passing passing string arraylist

////////////
        Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),MainActivity.class);
        intent.putStringArrayListExtra("KEY",stringArrayList);
        startActivity(intent);

/////////////////
ArrayList<String> stringArrayList = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("KEY");

Answer (score 3):

```
     i.setClass(LatestAlbums.this, AlbumDetails.class);
     i.putStringArrayListExtra("list", your song list);
     startActivity(i);
```

To get the array list in activity.

```
ArrayList<String> fetchList= new ArrayList<String>();
fetchList=  getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("list");
```

Hope this will help you.

For more reference use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374546/passing-arraylist-through-intent).

Answer (score 2):

Refers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45446452/send-arraylist-by-intent/54721728). I hope this example helps you.

**1. Your Song class should be implements Parcelable Class**

```
public class Song implements Parcelable { 
//Your setter and getter methods
}
```

**2. Put your arraylist to putParcelableArrayListExtra()**

```
public class ActivityA extends AppCompatActivity {
ArrayList<Song> songs;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityB.class)
            .putParcelableArrayListExtra("songs", (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) songs));
        }
    });
}
```

**3. In the ActivityB**

```
public class ActivityB extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    final ArrayList<Song> songs = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("songs");

    //Check the value in the console
    buttonCheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            for (Song value : songs) {
                System.out.println(value.getTitle());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the Songs class implement Serializable like this way.

`public class Songs implements Serializable{
      // your code here
}`.

In Activity One

```
Intent intent =  new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("Songs",arrSongs); //where arrSongs is object of  ArrayList<Songs>

intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

In SecondActivity where you want to retrieve the ArrayList object

```
 Bundle bundle =  getIntent().getExtras();
 private ArrayList<Songs> items;
 items = (ArrayList<Songs>)bundle.getSerializable("Songs");
```

Comment: Maybe should use class `Parcelable` instead of `Sertializable`