# pass Arraylist through intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I want to pass the taskItems

`ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> taskItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();`

through intent to the second activity

```
    ArrayList<String> stringArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    stringArr.add(KEY_TITLE);
    stringArr.add(KEY_INFO);
    stringArr.add(KEY_OBJECT);
    stringArr.add(KEY_LOCATION);

    ArrayList<Integer> intArr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    intArr.add(R.id.title);
    intArr.add(R.id.info);
    intArr.add(R.id.object);
    intArr.add(R.id.location);

    //Neue Oberfläche starten
    Intent in = new Intent(ListViewActivity.this, ListMenuItemActivity.class);
    in.putStringArrayListExtra("StringAdapter",stringArr);
    in.putIntegerArrayListExtra("intAdapter",intArr);
    ------>in.putStringArrayListExtra("taskItems",taskItems);

    startActivity(in);
```

I've marked the spot. 
How can i pass the `ArrayList` through Intent to my Activity?

Comment: Make JSONArray of ur list and pass it.

Comment: before posting questions, at least search similar questions available in SO. if you didnt get any solution, then only post. check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15790499/passing-arraylist-of-objects-between-activities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HashMap` extends `Serializable` interface, so you can pass an `ArrayList` of `Serializable` objects:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> taskItems = new ArrayList<>();
in.putExtra("taskItems", taskItems);
```

and fetch it like:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> taskItems = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) in
        .getSerializableExtra("taskItems");
```

Answer (score 1):

do this way

Send

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> hashMap= new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>()

Intent intent = new Intent(SourceActivity.this, DestinationActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("hashMap", hashMap);
startActivity(intent);
```

Recieve

```
  Intent intent = getIntent();    
   ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> hashMap = (ArrayList(HashMap<String, String>)) intent.getSerializableExtra("hashMap");
```

Comment: It's not an ArrayList of Strings, it's an ArrayList of HashMaps. This won't work.