# Issue with passing a Custom ArrayList through Intent with Serialize

Tags: android, arraylist

I am attempting to pass an array List of Custom objects through from one class to the other. I used a wrapper class to pass over the array List:

```
package perks;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PerkWrapper implements Serializable {

   private ArrayList<Perk> parliaments;

   public PerkWrapper(ArrayList<Perk> perks) {
      this.parliaments = perks;
   }

   public ArrayList<Perk> getParliaments() {
      return this.parliaments;
   }

}
```

I pass it like this:

```
i.putExtra("perks", player.perks);
```

Where player.perks is the arrayList containing teh Perk object
And i retrieve it like so:

```
PerkWrapper pw = (PerkWrapper) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("perks");
        plrPerks = pw.getParliaments();
        player.perks = plrPerks;
```

When i run the app, i get the following error:

```
Unable to start activity.. ClassCastException ArrayList cannot be cast to   
perks.perkwrapper
```

Here is my Perk class: (The object in the array List):

```
package perks;
public class Perk implements Parcelable {
public String name;
public String desc;
public int cost;

public int roundReq;
public int rankReq;

public int minusDec;
public int plusInc;
public int autoClick;
public int rewardBonus;

public Perk() {
    this.name = "";
    this.desc = "";
    this.cost = 0;
    this.roundReq = 1;
    this.rankReq = 1;
    this.minusDec = 1;
    this.plusInc = 1;
    this.autoClick = 1;
    this.rewardBonus = 1;
}

public Perk(Parcel in) {
    name = in.readString();
    desc = in.readString();
    cost = in.readInt();
    roundReq = in.readInt();
    rankReq = in.readInt();
    minusDec = in.readInt();
    plusInc = in.readInt();
    autoClick = in.readInt();
    rewardBonus = in.readInt();
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<Perk> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Perk>() {
    public Perk createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Perk(in);
    }

    public Perk[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Perk[size];
    }
};

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(name);
    dest.writeString(desc);
    dest.writeInt(cost);
    dest.writeInt(roundReq);
    dest.writeInt(rankReq);
    dest.writeInt(minusDec);
    dest.writeInt(plusInc);
    dest.writeInt(autoClick);
    dest.writeInt(rewardBonus);
}
```

}

How can i prevent this error from happening or are there any alternatives to passing array Lists simply? Thank you for your time

Comment: `public class PerkWrapper<Perk> extends ArrayList<Perk> implements Serializable`

Comment: is player.perks an instance of PerkWrapper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `player.perks` which is an `ArrayList` of `Perk` and in your other activity you are getting `PerkWrapper` and hence it is giving you error.You will need to do something like this

```
ArrayList<Perk> perks = (ArrayList<Perk>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("perks");
```

Comment: It worked. Do i still need to implement parcelable in Perk for it to work?

Comment: Yes Perk should be `Parcelable`.

Answer (score 0):

> Reply to @amit singh's Answer (My reputation not yet upto comment
>   level)

The method specified is possible possible only for arraylist of the format ArrayList. For custom objects, this is not applicable.

Answer (score -1):

To pass arraylist between activities, use-

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, secondActivity.class);
        intent.putStringArrayListExtra("list", samplelist);
        startActivity(intent);
```

In your receiving intent you need to do:

```
Intent i = getIntent();  
stock_list = i.getStringArrayListExtra("list");
```

Comment: This can only be used to pass string ArrayList not custom ArrayList.

Comment: For that you have to use Parceable or Serializable interface.

Comment: I know, I was just pointing it out for others, for passing custom arrayList using intent see the following question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15747727/pass-arraylist-of-user-defined-objects-to-intent-android

Comment: the question is about passing a custom arraylist