# how to pass list of objects through intent

Tags: java, android

I am trying to pass the list of object from one activity to another. But not able to send it.

Here is my code.

```
 setPrefBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent homePageIntent = new Intent(SetPreferences.this,
                        KlarityHome.class);// Connecting setPreferences page
                // with Klarity Home Page

               List<PracticeVO> tempList = new ArrayList<PracticeVO>();
               tempList.add(practiceObj);
                     homePageIntent.putExtra("SelectedPractice",       tempList.toArray());
                startActivity(homePageIntent);
            }
            });
```

And retriving in 2nd activity like this :
    Intent prefIntent = new Intent();
                List preferencedPractices = (List)   getIntent().getExtras().get("SelectedPractice");

```
            ArrayAdapter<PracticeVO> praticeAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<PracticeVO>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                    preferencedPractices);

              praticeAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            practiceSpin.setAdapter(praticeAdapter);
```

Comment: how you are retrieving

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17453297/passing-arraylist-of-string-arrays-from-one-activity-to-another-in-android

Comment: check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20421315/issue-with-passing-a-custom-arraylist-through-intent-with-serialize

Answer (score 1):

You need to use putExtra() function to pass values to another activity

```
Intent newIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
newIntent.putExtra("yourTxtField",yourTxtField.getText());
```

to receive you need to use other getIntent and Bundle.

```
Intent myIntent = getIntent();
Bundle valores  = myIntent.getExtras();

//Objeto que vai calcular os resultados
Resultado resultado = new Resultado();

//Recupera os valores recebidos pelo intent
double seuDinheiro  =  Double.parseDouble((String) valores.get("seuDinheiro").toString());
```

To pass objects see this SO post

[How do I pass an object from one activity to another on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906925/android-how-do-i-pass-an-object-from-one-activity-to-another)

[How to pass an object from one activity to another on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736389/how-to-pass-object-from-one-activity-to-another-in-android)

Comment: You can't pass objects as an extra like this

Answer (score 1):

Try in this manner

```
ArrayList<Object> object = new ArrayList<Object>();
Intent intent = new Intent(Current.class, Transfer.class);
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putSerializable("ARRAYLIST",(Serializable)object);
intent.putExtra("BUNDLE",args);
startActivity(intent);
```

In the Transfer.class

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle args = intent.getBundleExtra("BUNDLE");
ArrayList<Object> object = (ArrayList<Object>) args.getSerializable("ARRAYLIST");
```

Answer (score 0):

What type is `PracticeVO`? In order to do what you are intending, `PracticeVO` needs to implement the `Parcelable` interface (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html). Then you can use this version of the `putExtra()` method: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String, android.os.Parcelable[]).

Comment: PracticeVO is a class

Comment: I guess what I meant was: "What does it extend and/or implement?" I had assumed it was a class (or interface) given the name of the type.

Answer (score 0):

implement Serializable in your `PracticeVO` class file

When sending from an activity:

```
List<PracticeVO> PracticeVO = new ArrayList<PracticeVO>;
Intent intent = new Intent(SourceActivity.this, TargetActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("PracticeVO", ArrayList<PracticeVO> PracticeVO);
startactivity(PracticeVO);
```

At the receiver side:

```
List<Question> questions = new ArrayList<Question>();
questions = (ArrayList<Question>)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("QuestionListExtra");
```

source: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13601883/how-to-pass-arraylist-of-objects-from-one-to-another-activity-using-intent-in-an)

Answer (score 0):

Notification fundinProgram = (Notification) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(DETAIL_OBJECT);

Comment: I've formatted your code for you - but to make this answer actually useful, please include some explanation on how it solves the OP's issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve it this way:

- Make your model class (PracticeVO) as well as your Activity class (KlarityHome) implement Serializable.

  ```
  public class MyClass implements Serializable {...}
  ```
- In your activity class, store your objects in an ArrayList rather than a List.
- Finally, you can do this:

  ```
  // create intent
  Intent homePageIntent = new Intent(SetPreferences.this, KlarityHome.class);

  // create your ArrayList and add your item(s)
  List<PracticeVO> tempList = new ArrayList<PracticeVO>();
  tempList.add(practiceObj);

  // add your arraylist to your intent
  homePageIntent.putExtra("SelectedPractice", tempList);

  // go go go ;-)
  startActivity(homePageIntent);
  ```

I hope this helps. Merry coding!