# How to use the same ArrayList in different activities (Android and Java)

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-activity

I am working on a little app and needed a way of making it so when a button is pushed it opens up a random activity, and then doesn't open up that activity again.

I did this by making an ArrayList which is randomly sorted and has a number chosen from it. This number is then deleted. The number chosen is then used to open up one of the activities.

However, when I get to another activity I cannot use the same ArrayList from before (with all the same numbers in).

Is there a way to move the ArrayList from activity to activity?

Thanks in advance!

Here is my code for making the ArrayList and picking a number:

```
                int min = 1;
                int max = 3;
                ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                for(int i = min; i <= max; i++) list.add(i);
                Collections.shuffle(list);

                Integer x = list.get(0);
                list.remove(0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass it in your startActivity intent (intent.putExtra) or you can use a static variable in your application class:

[How to declare global variables in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708012/android-how-to-declare-global-variables)

For passing an ArrayList with an intent, this is a very useful post:

[Pass arraylist of user defined objects to Intent android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15747727/pass-arraylist-of-user-defined-objects-to-intent-android)

Basically, if you use all primitives you can pass them without creating parcelable objects to put into it. You also do not have to create a parcelable object (because objects that do not extend or implement parcelable cannot successfully be passed in an intent even though you will not see any errors).

Comment: Hi,thanks for getting back so quickly! I quite like the idea of passing it in my startActivity intent. I had a little search around and found something but I tried it and it doesn't seem to work. Would you be able to explain a little bit more about it to me? Thanks :)