# Error passing data between activities in Android

Tags: android

I'm making and android app that connects to some pages and via web scraping it extracts some content.

Yesterday I added a new server to get content but for some reason, it don't work, when starting next activity LogCat says

```
07-17 22:44:44.619    8393-8393/com.mixware.senpaimangareader W/ActivityThread﹕ Application com.mixware.senpaimangareader can be debugged on port 8100...
07-17 22:44:44.799    8408-8408/com.mixware.senpaimangareader W/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
07-17 22:44:44.989    8408-8408/com.mixware.senpaimangareader W/ActivityThread﹕ Application com.mixware.senpaimangareader can be debugged on port 8100...
```

Lots of times, and starts lots of procceses.

I've debuged the code with the new extraction, it is very low, but it works.
Then the code that generates all problems is

```
public void nextActivity(final ArrayList<Manga> mangas) {
    if (mangas == null || mangas.isEmpty()) (new getMangas(this)).execute("");
    else {
                Intent mIntent = new Intent(FullscreenActivity.this, MangaList.class);
                mIntent.putExtra("lista", mangas);

                startActivity(mIntent);

    }
}
```

You can see the full code in https://github.com/mixtoism/SenpaiMangaReader the files are FullScreenActivity.java and getMangas.java

Comment: Have you declared the activity in manifest? Do your second activity loads and you are not getting data , OR Second activity is not even loading ?

Comment: Yes, of course the app was working and i added a new case in getMangas switch and used it, with other case (case 1, case 0 is offline) it works well. The second activity runs but it don't gets the data

Comment: can you pl share the code of how you are retrieving the values from the intent extra?

Comment: ArrayList<Manga> mangas = (ArrayList<Manga>) this.getIntent().getSerializableExtra("lista");

Comment: for sending activity - try putting as mIntent.putSerializable("lista", mangas);

Comment: this doesnt exist, what i use is putExtra(String,Serializable) wich is in the API http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Comment: If it helps you, it only crashes if i choose the new font. But the instance mangas has value, it's not null and is correct. the thing i think it is is that is very big 2.800 elements of 200 bytes aprox

Comment: try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15747727/pass-arraylist-of-user-defined-objects-to-intent-android

Comment: finnally i wrote it in a binary file, and i load it in the othe activity