# java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object in Android passing ArrayList object

Tags: java, android, serialization, arraylist, mpandroidchart

I want to pass my ArrayList object to another activity, using a DataWrapper that implements `Serializable`. 
I followed the answer provided here: [Pass arraylist of user defined objects to Intent android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15747727/3879470).
I am starting the another Activity from `MPAndroidChart` library `PieChart`'s `OnChartGestureListener()`. This is how I passed my ArrayList object `threadList`:

```
mChart.setOnChartGestureListener(new OnChartGestureListener() {
@Override
public void onChartSingleTapped(MotionEvent me) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TextersSmsActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("threadList", new DataWrapper(threadList));
    MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
}
//.....
}
```

I implemented the DataWrapper class like this:

```
public class DataWrapper implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 100L;
private ArrayList<OneThread> threadList;

   public DataWrapper(ArrayList<OneThread> threadList) {
      this.threadList = threadList;
   }

   public ArrayList<OneThread> getThreadList() {
      return threadList;
   }
}
```

And getting the `Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object` error.
Here is my Logcat:

```
11-29 21:12:09.919: E/MessageQueue-JNI(21550): java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = com.myproj.DataWrapper)
11-29 21:12:09.919: E/MessageQueue-JNI(21550):  at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1316)
11-29 21:12:09.919: E/MessageQueue-JNI(21550):  at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1264)
11-29 21:12:09.919: E/MessageQueue-JNI(21550):  at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:618)
11-29 21:12:09.919: E/MessageQueue-JNI(21550):  at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1692)
11-29 21:12:09.919: E/MessageQueue-JNI(21550):  at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:636)
11-29 21:12:09.919: E/MessageQueue-JNI(21550):  at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:7013)
11-29 21:12:09.919: E/MessageQueue-JNI(21550):  at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:2076)
11-29 21:12:09.919: E/MessageQueue-JNI(21550):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1419)
11-29 21:12:09.919: E/MessageQueue-JNI(21550):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3424)
11-29 21:12:09.919: E/MessageQueue-JNI(21550):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3385)
11-29 21:12:09.919: E/MessageQueue-JNI(21550):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:817)
11-29 21:12:09.919: E/MessageQueue-JNI(21550):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3627)
11-29 21:12:09.919: E/MessageQueue-JNI(21550):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3595)
11-29 21:12:09.919: E/MessageQueue-JNI(21550):  at com.myproj.MainActivity$11.onChartSingleTapped(MainActivity.java:967)
11-29 21:12:09.919: E/MessageQueue-JNI(21550):  at com.github.mikephil.charting.listener.PieRadarChartTouchListener.onSingleTapUp(PieRadarChartTouchListener.java:89)
11-29 21:12:09.919: E/MessageQueue-JNI(21550):  at android.view.GestureDetector.onTouchEvent(GestureDetector.java:595)
11-29 21:12:09.919: E/MessageQueue-JNI(21550):  at com.github.mikephil.charting.listener.PieRadarChartTouchListener.onTouch(PieRadarChartTouchListener.java:40)
11-29 21:12:09.919: E/MessageQueue-JNI(21550):  at com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieRadarChartBase.onTouchEvent(PieRadarChartBase.java:56)
11-29 21:12:09.919: E/MessageQueue-JNI(21550):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7706)
11-29 21:12:09.919: E/MessageQueue-JNI(21550):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
11-29 21:12:09.919: E/MessageQueue-JNI(21550):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
11-29 21:12:09.919: E/MessageQueue-JNI(21550):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
11-29 21:12:09.919: E/MessageQueue-JNI(21550):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
11-29 21:12:09.919: E/MessageQueue-JNI(21550):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
11-29 21:12:09.919: E/MessageQueue-JNI(21550):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
11-29 21:12:09.919: E/MessageQueue-JNI(21550):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
11-29 21:12:09.919: E/MessageQueue-JNI(21550):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
11-29 21:12:09.919: E/MessageQueue-JNI(21550):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
11-29 21:12:09.919: E/MessageQueue-JNI(21550):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
11-29 21:12:09.919: E/MessageQueue-JNI(21550):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
11-29 21:12:09.919: E/MessageQueue-JNI(21550):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
11-29 21:12:09.919: E/MessageQueue-JNI(21550):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2068)
11-29 21:12:09.919: E/MessageQueue-JNI(21550):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1515)
11-29 21:12:09.919: E/MessageQueue-JNI(21550):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2458)
11-29 21:12:09.919: E/MessageQueue-JNI(21550):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:268)
11-29 21:12:09.919: E/MessageQueue-JNI(21550):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2016)
11-29 21:12:09.919: E/MessageQueue-JNI(21550):  at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7886)
11-29 21:12:09.919: E/MessageQueue-JNI(21550):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3947)
11-29 21:12:09.919: E/MessageQueue-JNI(21550):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3826)
11-29 21:12:09.919: E/MessageQueue-JNI(21550):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3392)
11-29 21:12:09.919: E/MessageQueue-JNI(21550):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3442)
11-29 21:12:09.919: E/MessageQueue-JNI(21550):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3411)
11-29 21:12:09.919: E/MessageQueue-JNI(21550):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3518)
11-29 21:12:09.919: E/MessageQueue-JNI(21550):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3419)
11-29 21:12:09.919: E/MessageQueue-JNI(21550):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3575)
11-29 21:12:09.919: E/MessageQueue-JNI(21550):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3392)
11-29 21:12:09.919: E/MessageQueue-JNI(21550):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3442)
11-29 21:12:09.919: E/MessageQueue-JNI(21550):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3411)
11-29 21:12:09.919: E/MessageQueue-JNI(21550):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3419)
11-29 21:12:09.919: E/MessageQueue-JNI(21550):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3392)
11-29 21:12:09.919: E/MessageQueue-JNI(21550):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5532)
11-29 21:12:09.919: E/MessageQueue-JNI(21550):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doP
```

I followed the answer (to pass array list objects) in the link above but getting the Error, what is causing the error and how to remove it?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Your `OneThread` Class also should implement `Serializable`. All the sub classes and inner sub classes must implement `Serializable`.

Comment: My `OneThread` class had another field `ArrayList<Cls2>` making `Cls2` also serializable solved it.

Comment: @mohammed, thanks for your note to make field classes also serializable ;)

Comment: My class was already implemented Serializable. but getting same issue

Comment: Exactly! All the custom inner classes must be serializable also.

Comment: Thanksssss a lot bro you saved my hours:) +10 to you