# What is the life span of a static variable of a library class for Android?

Tags: java, android, static

I have noticed [the answer of a SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475978/using-static-variables-in-android)  is true for certain devices (i.e. a static variable of an Android library lives from one activity to another of an app), but not for other devices.

Here is a code snippet to illustrate this

```
public class LibraryFoo{
    static List<String> listFoo= new ArrayList<String>();

    //The following method is called from many activities 
    public static methodFoo(){
        //do something to listFoo
    }
}
```

The static variable listFoo persists from one activity to another for some Android devices, but is recreated for each activity for other Android devices.

Does my observation make any sense? Could anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Which devices recreate it? Does it happen every single time, or only sometimes?

Comment: static variables are on the heap in a permanent area. You can refer to the static variable using class name. The link you posted does no have anything related to any device. Have you read the full post?

Comment: @Raghav: the observation is based on our apps' logs. It appears to be every single time when a new activity is started (sorry but I am not 100% sure). For example, some LG tablets do this.

Comment: @Raghunandan, the static variable is a private one used by a public static method of the library class. Yes, I have read the post multiple times, and noticed: "So, think of it as living as long as your app runs."

Comment: If you are referencing static variables in another activity, the class in which it is declared will not be garbage collected. When activity is destroyed and then garbage collection takes place.

Comment: @Raghunandan: the static variable is a private variable, not referenced by any activity.  It is used by a public static method of the same library class.  Could this be a problem?

Comment: As noted in a comment to the post you reference "it'll be retained until your entire process is destroyed." (Which can be good and bad, you will have to maintain that list if you choose that statics approach.)

Comment: @CharlieCollins: This is where I am not clear.  Let me give an example of what happens.  Activity A calls LibraryFoo.methodFoo() which changes the static variable listFoo, the A starts activity B that calls LibraryFoo.methodFoo() too.  I am not sure what is supposed to happen to listFoo.  On some devices, listFoo persists, but not on other devices. The app's code does not do anything to maintain listFoo.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you been confusing that ,Library variables will remain constant until application dies.

Life time of a Library method variable is until the execution of method(Library is just a concept of encapsulation(Hiding data behind an interface)).

Comment: the variable referred to is not a method variable.  It is a static variable of the class that has the method.

Comment: @Hong, Don't use this procedure, Go for Bundle to store. Reason is - as Android have different Context. It recreates everytime.

Comment: The static variable is not associated with any context.  That is the intention. The information is not passed from one activity to another.  It is used by a static method of the library class.