# How to call a method defined in one activity, from another

Tags: android-activity, methods, call, subclass

I'm having two activities, activity A and activity B.
I've defined a method in a class inside activity A.
Activity B has a class and its subclass.

Now I need to call the method from subclass.
As I cannot create the same method again within the subclass.

Comment: Thank you Mr.Frank.. This syntax worked me well..  Can i know what is the advantage of using static keyword.. Im jus a beginner.. And im curious to know about it..

Comment: Please, refer to this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475978/using-static-variables-in-android)

Comment: This is very helpful.. Thank you once again Mr.Frank..

Comment: I converted my comment to an answer, so that you can accept it and remove the post from the Unanswered Question Queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare your method as `protected static`. Then, from B, call it so: `A.myMethod();`