# android inner fragment variable access

Tags: android, android-fragments, static

I have a `DialogFragment` that own 2 inner `Fragments` (which are displayed as tabs in a `ViewPager`).

The `DialogFragment` is called as usual, using a `newInstance()` pattern, with a `Bundle` containing a simple int (an id, for database fetching). It then calls its 2 `Fragments`, which will need the int.

I have 2 options here :

- having a `static int` field of my `DialogFragment`, which would be instanciated in `onCreateView()` when I `getArguments()`, and read inside my inner Fragments
- using another `newInstance()` pattern inside my inner fragments and passing the int along

What's the difference between these 2 ways ?

Answer (score 0):

In your case, both of them are okey. Personally, I'd rather use the `newInstance()` approach, since I think is cleaner.

Also, keep in mind that [static objects in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475978/using-static-variables-in-android) are reclaimed when the app is destroyed, and not before.